# Jqgrid + CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, jqgrid

I tried to make jqgrid work with codeigniter, but I could not do it, I only want to show the data from the table in json format... but nothing happens.. but i dont know what i am doing wrong, i cant see the table with the content i am calling.

my controller

```
class Grid extends Controller
{

  public function f()
  {

       $this->load->model('dbgrid');
       $var['grid'] =  $this->dbgrid->getcontentfromtable();

       foreach($var['grid'] as $row) {
        $responce->rows[$i]['id']=$row->id;
        $responce->rows[$i]['cell']=array($row->id,$row->id_catalogo);

       }
     $json = json_encode($responce);
       $this->load->view('vgrid',$json);



  } 


  function load_view_grid()
  {

    $this->load->view('vgrid');


  }


}
```

my model

```
class Dbgrid extends Model{

function getcontentfromtable()
{


  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM anuncios';
  $query = $this->db->query($sql);
  $result = $query->result();


  return $result;   
}
```

my view(script)

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
 jQuery("#list27").jqGrid({
        url:'http://localhost/sitio/index.php/grid/f',
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "post",
        height: 255,
        width: 600,
        colNames:['ID','ID_CATALOGO'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'id',index:'id', width:65, sorttype:'int'},
            {name:'id_catalogo',index:'id_catalogo', sorttype:'int'}


        ],
        rowNum:50,
        rowTotal: 2000,
        rowList : [20,30,50],
        loadonce:true,
        rownumbers: true,
        rownumWidth: 40,
        gridview: true,
        pager: '#pager27',
        sortname: 'item_id',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "asc",
        caption: "Loading data from server at once" 
    });

});
```

hope someone help me

Comment: Oh god i wish i could edit your post and fix your mistakes in using `Code Blocks`. Do you have an example of the output of `http://localhost/sitio/index.php/grid/f` ?

Comment: hahah ....sorry 

this is the output  {"rows":{"":{"id":"11","cell":["11","225101503"]}}}

Answer (score 3):

The data produced by the server which you post in the comment

```
{"rows":{"":{"id":"11","cell":["11","225101503"]}}}
```

have wrong format. The output should looks like

```
{ 
  "total": "xxx", 
  "page": "yyy", 
  "records": "zzz",
  "rows" : [
    {"id" :"1", "cell" :["cell11", "cell12", "cell13"]},
    {"id" :"2", "cell":["cell21", "cell22", "cell23"]},
      ...
  ]
}
```

(see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data). So it should be at least like

```
{"rows":[{"id":"11","cell":["11","225101503"]}]}
```

In general if you define a `jsonReader`, you will be able to read almost any data. The data which you produce can be readed only by `jsonReader` defined with the functions (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#jsonreader_as_function and [jquery with ASP.NET MVC - calling ajax enabled web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835957/jquery-with-asp-net-mvc-calling-ajax-enabled-web-service/2836817#2836817)). The simplest way for you will be to change your server code to produce the data in a standard formet (see above), which can be readed by the standard `jsonReader`.

And one more small remark. Using of `sorttype` has no effect for `datatype: "json"`. Parameter `sorttype` works only with sorting of **local** data. In case of `datatype: "json"` the server will be responsible for correct data sorting. jqGrid send to the server only the name of column, which user choose for the data sorting.

Comment: Hi Oleg, I can generate the correct format of the output, but I still cant see the result in the table 

This is what I get 

{"rows":[

  {"id":"1","cell":["1","225101503"]},
  {"id":"3","cell":["3","225101503"]},
  {"id":"4","cell":["4","225101503"]},
  {"id":"6","cell":["6","225101503"]},
  {"id":"5","cell":["5","225101503"]},
  {"id":"7","cell":["7","452101500"]},
  {"id":"8","cell":["8","330000000"]},
  {"id":"9","cell":["9","110101511"]},
  {"id":"10","cell":["10","110101502"]},
  {"id":"11","cell":["11","225101503"]}
 
 ]
}

I can see the table with the data, but outside the model(MVC).

Comment: There are something important which you don't write. Your code and data are not perfect, they have no information about page, total and records, but all should work. I saved your json data in json.txt file and created a small html file with your JavaScript: ivan.htm. To make all easy I just replaced post to get. So try this one http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ivan0.htm. It works. To fix problem with negative row numbers I set `rowNum:0` and we can see http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ivan.htm. So you have your problem somewhere else. Compare my html code with your code as browser source.

Comment: Hi Oleg, 
 Thanks for your support. 
 I found what was the problem and when I figured it out, I wanted to kill myself. I forgot to include a js file.

And I have 'get' in mtype, because CI and jqGrid have different posting methods, CodeIgniter(POST) and jqGrid(GET).

Thank You.

Comment: You welmome! One say: "It is very difficult to find a black cat in a dark room. Espetially if the cat is not here." In software development we spend frequently a lot of our time for searching a wrong reason. And find out at the end a real reason of our problem somewhere else. At the end it's only important, that the problem is solved. One should try to be philosophical in such situations. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I am a new programmer in code igniter.
I am trying to integrate jqgrid with code igniter and after seven hours i came to a successful point where jqgrid and code igniter is fully integrated with search option.

At first, write a model in your application/model directory. The code is......

```
class JqgridSample extends CI_Model {

  function getAllData($start,$limit,$sidx,$sord,$where){
    $this->db->select('id,name,email,passport,phone,fax,address');
    $this->db->limit($limit);
    if($where != NULL)
        $this->db->where($where,NULL,FALSE);
    $this->db->order_by($sidx,$sord);
    $query = $this->db->get('info',$limit,$start);

    return $query->result();
  }
}
```

Then, write a controller in your application/controller directory. The code is

```
class Demo extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('JqgridSample');
}

function jqGrid(){
$this->load->view('showGrid');
}

function loadData(){
    $page = isset($_POST['page'])?$_POST['page']:1; 
    $limit = isset($_POST['rows'])?$_POST['rows']:10; 
    $sidx = isset($_POST['sidx'])?$_POST['sidx']:'name'; 
    $sord = isset($_POST['sord'])?$_POST['sord']:'';         
    $start = $limit*$page - $limit; 
    $start = ($start<0)?0:$start; 

    $where = ""; 
    $searchField = isset($_POST['searchField']) ? $_POST['searchField'] : false;
    $searchOper = isset($_POST['searchOper']) ? $_POST['searchOper']: false;
    $searchString = isset($_POST['searchString']) ? $_POST['searchString'] : false;

    if ($_POST['_search'] == 'true') {
        $ops = array(
        'eq'=>'=', 
        'ne'=>'<>',
        'lt'=>'<', 
        'le'=>'<=',
        'gt'=>'>', 
        'ge'=>'>=',
        'bw'=>'LIKE',
        'bn'=>'NOT LIKE',
        'in'=>'LIKE', 
        'ni'=>'NOT LIKE', 
        'ew'=>'LIKE', 
        'en'=>'NOT LIKE', 
        'cn'=>'LIKE', 
        'nc'=>'NOT LIKE' 
        );
        foreach ($ops as $key=>$value){
            if ($searchOper==$key) {
                $ops = $value;
            }
        }
        if($searchOper == 'eq' ) $searchString = $searchString;
        if($searchOper == 'bw' || $searchOper == 'bn') $searchString .= '%';
        if($searchOper == 'ew' || $searchOper == 'en' ) $searchString = '%'.$searchString;
        if($searchOper == 'cn' || $searchOper == 'nc' || $searchOper == 'in' || $searchOper == 'ni') $searchString = '%'.$searchString.'%';

        $where = "$searchField $ops '$searchString' "; 

    }

    if(!$sidx) 
        $sidx =1;
    $count = $this->db->count_all_results('info'); 
    if( $count > 0 ) {
        $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit);    
    } else {
        $total_pages = 0;
    }

    if ($page > $total_pages) 
        $page=$total_pages;
    $query = $this->JqgridSample->getAllData($start,$limit,$sidx,$sord,$where); 
    $responce->page = $page;
    $responce->total = $total_pages;
    $responce->records = $count;
    $i=0;
    foreach($query as $row) {
        $responce->rows[$i]['id']=$row->id;
        $responce->rows[$i]['cell']=array($row->name,$row->email,$row->passport,$row->phone,$row->fax,$row->address);
        $i++;
    }

    echo json_encode($responce);
}
}
```

And finally you write a view in your application/views directory..

```
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url()?>application/views/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" />

    <link type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url()?>application/views/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url()?>application/views/css/plugins/searchFilter.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <style>
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 75%;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>application/views/js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>application/views/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>application/views/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>


    <title>Codeigniter With JQGrid</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>Codeigniter With JQGrid</h1>
    <?php
        $ci =& get_instance();
        $base_url = base_url();
    ?>
    <table id="list"></table><!--Grid table-->
    <div id="pager"></div>  <!--pagination div-->
    </center>
</body>


<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function (){
            jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
                url:'<?=$base_url.'index.php/demo/loadData'?>',      //another controller function for generating data
                mtype : "post",             //Ajax request type. It also could be GET
                datatype: "json",            //supported formats XML, JSON or Arrray
                colNames:['Name','Email','Passport','Phone','Fax','Address'],       //Grid column headings
                colModel:[
                    {name:'name',index:'name', width:100, align:"left"},
                    {name:'email',index:'email', width:150, align:"left"},
                    {name:'passport',index:'passport', width:100, align:"right"},
                    {name:'phone',index:'phone', width:100, align:"right"},
                    {name:'fax',index:'fax', width:100, align:"right"},
                    {name:'address',index:'address', width:100, align:"right"},
                ],
                rowNum:10,
                width: 750,
                //height: 300,
                rowList:[10,20,30],
                pager: '#pager',
                sortname: 'id',
                viewrecords: true,
                rownumbers: true,
                gridview: true,
                caption:"List Of Person"
            }).navGrid('#pager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
        });
    </script>
```

For the view file for myself i create two folder in views directory js and css.
and in js foder i place the jquery-1.5.2.min.js, grid.locale-en.js(views/js/i18n/), jquery.jqGrid.min.js which you find in jqgrid package.

In a same way jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css, ui.jqgrid.css needed that also is available in jqgrid package.

for running full process you have to create a database named jqgrid_sample and in the database create a table named info contains fields...

id

name

email

passport

phone

fax

address

thats it. enjoy. good bye.

Comment: $responce is not declared. What should it be?

Answer (score 0):

These Solution is Cover full JqGrid Data Load and CRUD.
This is Very Simple Task. Just go through the following steps and enjoy.

1. Write a Model just like below

   ```
   class gridAction_model extends CI_Model {

   public function __construct() {
       $this->load->database();
   }

   function getAllTeacherDesignation($start, $limit, $sidx, $sord, $where) {

       $this->db->select('DesignationId,DesignationName,Description,Status');
       $this->db->limit($limit);
       if ($where != NULL)
           $this->db->where($where, NULL, FALSE);
       $this->db->order_by($sidx, $sord);
       $query = $this->db->get('TeacherDesignation', $limit, $start);

       return $query->result();
   }

   function insert_teacherDesignation($data) {
       return $this->db->insert('TeacherDesignation', $data);
   }

   function update_teacherDesignation($id, $data) {
       $this->db->where('DesignationId', $id);
       return $this->db->update('TeacherDesignation', $data);
   }

   function delete_teacherDesignation($id) {
       $this->db->where('DesignationId', $id);
       $this->db->delete('TeacherDesignation');
   }
   ```

   }
2. Now Add the following Method to the Controller Class

   ```
       class grid_action extends CI_Controller {

   public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->load->helper("form");
       $this->load->model("gridAction_model");
   }

   public function loadTeacherDesignationData() {

       $page = isset($_POST['page']) ? $_POST['page'] : 1;
       $limit = isset($_POST['rows']) ? $_POST['rows'] : 10;
       $sidx = isset($_POST['sidx']) ? $_POST['sidx'] : 'DesignationName';
       $sord = isset($_POST['sord']) ? $_POST['sord'] : '';
       $start = $limit * $page - $limit;
       $start = ($start < 0) ? 0 : $start;

       $where = "";
       $searchField = isset($_POST['searchField']) ? $_POST['searchField'] : false;
       $searchOper = isset($_POST['searchOper']) ? $_POST['searchOper'] : false;
       $searchString = isset($_POST['searchString']) ? $_POST['searchString'] : false;

       if ($_POST['_search'] == 'true') {
           $ops = array(
               'eq' => '=',
               'ne' => '<>',
               'lt' => '<',
               'le' => '<=',
               'gt' => '>',
               'ge' => '>=',
               'bw' => 'LIKE',
               'bn' => 'NOT LIKE',
               'in' => 'LIKE',
               'ni' => 'NOT LIKE',
               'ew' => 'LIKE',
               'en' => 'NOT LIKE',
               'cn' => 'LIKE',
               'nc' => 'NOT LIKE'
           );
           foreach ($ops as $key => $value) {
               if ($searchOper == $key) {
                   $ops = $value;
               }
           }
           if ($searchOper == 'eq')
               $searchString = $searchString;
           if ($searchOper == 'bw' || $searchOper == 'bn')
               $searchString .= '%';
           if ($searchOper == 'ew' || $searchOper == 'en')
               $searchString = '%' . $searchString;
           if ($searchOper == 'cn' || $searchOper == 'nc' || $searchOper == 'in' || $searchOper == 'ni')
               $searchString = '%' . $searchString . '%';

           $where = "$searchField $ops '$searchString' ";
       }

       if (!$sidx)
           $sidx = 1;
       $count = $this->db->count_all_results('TeacherDesignation');
       if ($count > 0) {
           $total_pages = ceil($count / $limit);
       } else {
           $total_pages = 0;
       }

       if ($page > $total_pages)
           $page = $total_pages;

       $query = $this->gridAction_model->getAllTeacherDesignation($start, $limit, $sidx, $sord, $where);

       $responce = new stdClass;

       $responce->page = $page;
       $responce->total = $total_pages;
       $responce->records = $count;
       $i = 0;

       foreach ($query as $row) {
           $responce->rows[$i]['id'] = $row->DesignationId;
           $responce->rows[$i]['cell'] = array($row->DesignationId, $row->DesignationName, $row->Description, $row->Status);
           $i++;
       }
       echo json_encode($responce);
   }

   public function crudTeacherDesignation() {

       $oper = $this->input->post('oper');
       $id = $this->input->post('id');
       $DesignationId = $this->input->post('DesignationId');
       $DesignationName = $this->input->post('DesignationName');
       $Description = $this->input->post('Description');
       $Status = $this->input->post('Status');

       switch ($oper) {
           case 'add':
               $data = array('DesignationId' => $DesignationId, 'DesignationName' => $DesignationName, 'Description' => $Description, 'Status' => $Status);
               $this->gridAction_model->insert_teacherDesignation($data);
               break;
           case 'edit':
               $data = array('DesignationId' => $DesignationId, 'DesignationName' => $DesignationName, 'Description' => $Description, 'Status' => $Status);
               $this->gridAction_model->update_teacherDesignation($DesignationId, $data);
               break;
           case 'del':
               $this->gridAction_model->delete_teacherDesignation($DesignationId);
               break;
       }
   }
   ```

   }
3. Add the Script at View

   ```
    <table id="gridDesignation"> </table>

    <div id="pager"> </div>





           $(document).ready(function () {

       jQuery("#gridDesignation").jqGrid({
           url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>grid_action/loadTeacherDesignationData',                
           mtype : "post",              //Ajax request type. It also could be GET
           datatype: "json",            //supported formats XML, JSON or Arrray
           colNames:['Designation ID','Designation Name','Description','Status'],       //Grid column headings
           colModel:[
               {name:'DesignationId',index:'DesignationId', width:100, align:"left", editable:true, editrules:{required:true}},
               {name:'DesignationName',index:'DesignationName', width:150, align:"left",editable:true,editrules:{required:true}},
               {name:'Description',index:'Description', width:100, align:"left", sortable:false, editable:true,editrules:{required:true}},
               {name:'Status',index:'Status', width:100, align:"right",editable:true,editrules:{required:true}, 
                   edittype:'select', editoptions:{value:"1:Active;0:InActive"}
               }
           ],
           rownumbers: true,
           rowNum:10,
           width: 750,
           height: "100%",
           rowList:[10,20,30],
           pager: jQuery('#pager'),
           sortname: 'DesignationName',
           autowidth: true,
           viewrecords: true,            
           gridview: true,  
           ondblClickRow: function(id){              
               $("#gridDesignation").editGridRow(id, {closeAfterEdit:true,mtype:'POST'});                
           },
           sortorder: "desc",       
           editurl: '<?php echo base_url() ?>grid_action/crudTeacherDesignation', //URL Process CRUD
           multiselect: false,
           caption:"List Of Teacher Designation"
       }).navGrid('#pager',
       {view:true,edit:true,add:true,del:true},
       {closeOnEscape:true},
       {closeOnEscape:true},
       {closeOnEscape:true},
       {closeOnEscape:true},
       {
           closeOnEscape:true,closeAfterSearch:false,multipleSearch:false, 
           multipleGroup:false, showQuery:false,
           drag:true,showOnLoad:false,sopt:['cn'],resize:false,
           caption:'Search Record', Find:'Search', 
           Reset:'Reset Search'
       }
   );        

   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Please be warned the example code of triand used here many times has **SQL-injection risk**. before generating `$where` string u should escape your searchString like;

**replace this:**

```
$where = "$searchField $ops '$searchString' ";
```

**with this:**

```
$searchString = mysql_real_escape_string($searchString);
$where = "$searchField $ops '$searchString' ";
```