# Load data from Webservice (asmx) to jqgrid. Please help me

Tags: web-services, json, jqgrid, asmx

I create a Sample to test jqgrid.

GetDataService.asmx:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ExampleJqGrid
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for GetDataService
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [ScriptService]
    [ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class GetDataService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string GetProduct()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=NGUYEN-LAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ProductDB;Integrated Security=True");
            //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Products", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Products", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];            
            GetJSONFromDataTable getJsonDataTable = new GetJSONFromDataTable();
            string json = getJsonDataTable.GetJSONString(dt);
            string jonsData = GetJSONFromDataTable.JsonForJqgrid(dt, 10, 10, 2);
            return jonsData;
        }
    }
}
```

GetJSONFromDataTable.cs

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace ExampleJqGrid
{
    public class GetJSONFromDataTable
    {public static string JsonForJqgrid(DataTable dt, int pageSize, int totalRecords,int page) 
         {
             int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);
             StringBuilder jsonBuilder = new StringBuilder();
             jsonBuilder.Append("{");
             jsonBuilder.Append("\"total\":" + totalPages + ",\"page\":" + page + ",\"records\":" + (totalRecords) + ",\"rows\"");
             jsonBuilder.Append(":[");
             for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) 
             {
                 jsonBuilder.Append("{\"i\":"+ (i) +",\"cell\":[");  
                 for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++) 
                 {           
                     jsonBuilder.Append("\""); 
                     jsonBuilder.Append(dt.Rows[i][j].ToString());
                     jsonBuilder.Append("\",");
                 }
                 jsonBuilder.Remove(jsonBuilder.Length - 1, 1);
                 jsonBuilder.Append("]},");
             }
             jsonBuilder.Remove(jsonBuilder.Length - 1, 1);
             jsonBuilder.Append("]");
             jsonBuilder.Append("}");
             return jsonBuilder.ToString();        
         }

    }
}
```

GetJSONFromDataTable.cs

```
public static string JsonForJqgrid(DataTable dt, int pageSize, int totalRecords,int page) 
{
    int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);
    StringBuilder jsonBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    jsonBuilder.Append("{");
    jsonBuilder.Append("\"total\":" + totalPages + ",\"page\":" + page + ",\"records\":" + (totalRecords) + ",\"rows\"");
    jsonBuilder.Append(":[");
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) 
    {
        jsonBuilder.Append("{\"i\":"+ (i) +",\"cell\":[");  
        for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++) 
        {           
            jsonBuilder.Append("\""); 
            jsonBuilder.Append(dt.Rows[i][j].ToString());
            jsonBuilder.Append("\",");
        }
        jsonBuilder.Remove(jsonBuilder.Length - 1, 1);
        jsonBuilder.Append("]},");
    }
    jsonBuilder.Remove(jsonBuilder.Length - 1, 1);
    jsonBuilder.Append("]");
    jsonBuilder.Append("}");
    return jsonBuilder.ToString();        
}
```

default.asp

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"
         Inherits="ExampleJqGrid._Default" %>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Resources/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Resources/js/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Resources/js/ui.multiselect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Resources/js/jquery.layout.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Resources/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Resources/js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Resources/js/jqDnR.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Resources/js/jqModal.js"></script>
<link href="Resources/themes/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<link href="Resources/themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" />


<script type="text/javascript">

function getProducts() 
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "/GetDataService.asmx/GetProduct",
        data:"{}",  // For empty input data use "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "'GET'",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        //success: successFunction
         /*complete*/success: function(jsondata) 
         {
         alert(jsondata);
            var thegrid = jQuery("#list")[0];
            thegrid.addJSONData(JSON.parse(jsondata));
         }
    });
}
function dataBindToGrid() 
{
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
        datatype: getProducts(), 
        colNames: ['ProductId', 'ProductName', 'Description', 'Price'],
        colModel: [{ name: 'ProductId', index: 'ProductId', width: 200, align: 'left' },
                    { name: 'ProductName', index: 'ProductName', width: 200, align: 'left' },
                    { name: 'Description', index: 'Description', width: 200, align: 'left' },
                    { name: 'Price', index: 'Price', width: 200, align: 'left' }
                   ],
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50, 100],
        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        //imgpath: '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Resources/themes/redmond/images") %>',
        imgpath: '~/Resources/themes/redmond/images',
        width: 300,
        viewrecords: true
    }).navGrid(pager, { edit: true, add: false, del: false, search: false });

}
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnAdd").click(dataBindToGrid);  

});

</script>
```

```
        <table id="list" class="scroll">
        </table>            
        <div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div> 
        <button id="btnAdd" >Load Data</button>            
        <asp:TextBox ID="hidenfield" runat = "server" style="display:none"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
</form>
```

When i alert jsondata string , it return null.

Please review and help me to load data to jqgrid

Best regards

Answer (score 3):

You example have a lot of problems. For example

- If you use `[WebMethod, ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]` attribute on the web method and `[ScriptService]` on the the web service class, then the output parameter will be **automatically converted to JSON**. (see [asmx web service, json, javascript/jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445859/asmx-web-service-json-javascript-jquery/3446517#3446517) for example). Then you will not need implementthe functions like `JsonForJqgrid`.
- You use very old template for your program. The usage of `datatype` as function for JSON data is no more needed. The usage of very old jqGrid parameters `imgpath` and `class="scroll"` in HTML which no more used since many versions of jqGrid show also that you use an very old template for your program.
- small errors like `type: "'GET'"` instead of `type: 'GET'` or `type: "GET"`.

If you will follow the way with the usage of `datatype` as function you will receive problems if you decide implement data paging of searching in your application.

I recommend you better look at some other examples like [jqgrid Page 1 of x pager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161302/jqgrid-page-1-of-x-pager/3161542#3161542), [jqgrid setGridParam datatype:local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169408/jqgrid-setgridparam-datatypelocal/3170652#3170652) or 
[jquery with ASP.NET MVC - calling ajax enabled web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835957/jquery-with-asp-net-mvc-calling-ajax-enabled-web-service/2836817#2836817). You can aslo download a working example http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/WebServicesPostToJqGrid.zip which I created as a part of the http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/pager-not-working-for-me-where-am-i-doing-wrong answer or http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/VS2008jQueryMVC.zip or  http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jQueryMVC.zip (see the another old answer [jquery with ASP.NET MVC - calling ajax enabled web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835957/jquery-with-asp-net-mvc-calling-ajax-enabled-web-service/2836817#2836817))

**UPDATED**: You have also the wrong order of the JavaScript files. The `ui.multiselect.css` is not loaded as all. You should change it to

Including of `jqDnR.js` and `jqModal.js` is not needed. It should be a part of `jquery.jqGrid.js` if you check the corresponding modules during [jqGrid downloading](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6). The `jquery.layout.js` are not needed for jqGrid. You should include it only if you use it separately.

Comment: @Nguyen Ngo: I found more errors in your code and updated my answer.