# Jqgrid not show Data

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

I using file *.ashx to get data from database. When I alert jsondata.responseText , it show json string

Respond text is:

```
{
 "total":2,
 "page":5,
 "record":10,
 "row":[
     {"i":0, "cell""["1","Desktop","Desktop Description","200"]},
     {"i":1, "cell""["2","Laptop","Laptop Description","1000"]},
     {"i":2, "cell""["2","DVD","DVD Description","100"]},
     {"i":3, "cell":["","","",""]}
 ]
}
```

But jqgrid not show data.

Please review my code and help me please !

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Sample_Json_Jqgrid._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>

    <%--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/themes/coffee/grid.css" title="steel" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="Resources/themes/jqModal.css" />--%>
    <link href="Resources/css/ui.jqgrid.css"  media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Resources/themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link href="Resources/src/css/jquery.searchFilter.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Resources/src/css/ui.jqgrid.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Resources/src/css/ui.multiselect.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="Resources/js/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Resources/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Resources/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Resources/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Resources/src/grid.base.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Resources/src/ui.multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Resources/src/grid.celledit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Resources/src/grid.common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Resources/src/grid.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Resources/src/grid.formedit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Resources/src/grid.grouping.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Resources/src/grid.import.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Resources/src/grid.inlinedit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Resources/src/grid.jqueryui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Resources/src/grid.loader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Resources/src/grid.postext.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Resources/src/grid.setcolumns.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Resources/src/grid.subgrid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Resources/src/grid.tbltogrid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Resources/src/grid.treegrid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Resources/src/jqDnR.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Resources/src/jqModal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Resources/src/jquery.fmatter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Resources/src/jquery.searchFilter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Resources/src/JsonXml.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">  
    <div>
        <table id="grid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        </table>
        <div id="pager" style="text-align: center;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="Resources/js/app.grid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

File javascript to jqgrid : app.grid.js

```
var mydata ;
function CreateGrid()
{     
   jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        colNames:['ProductId','ProductName','Description','Price'], 
        colModel:[ 
            {name:'ProductId',index:'ProductId',sorttype:"text",hidden:false},
            {name:'ProductName',index:'ProductName',sorttype:"text",resizable:false,
             width:100,sortable:true,align:'left',editable:true},
            {name:'Description',index:'Description',sorttype:"text",resizable:false,
             width:1000,sortable:true,align:'left',editable:true}, 
            {name:'Price',index:'designation',sorttype:"int",resizable:false,
             width:100,sortable:true,align:'left',editable:true}
        ],
        rowNum: 1,
        rowList: [5, 10, 15],
        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        imgpath: 'themes/redmond/images',
        sortname: 'ProductId',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption: 'Products'
    }).jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:true,add:true,del:true});
    BinDataGrid();
}

function BinDataGrid()
{
    $("#grid").clearGridData();
    jQuery(function($) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "'POST'",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "GetDataHandler.ashx",
            data: "{}",
            complete:  function(jsondata, stat)
            {
                window.alert("Status received is " + stat);
                window.alert("Response text is: " + jsondata.responseText);
                if (stat == "success")
                {
                    var thegrid = jQuery("#grid")[0];
                    thegrid.addJSONData(eval("(" + jsondata.responseText + ")"));
                }
            }
        });
    })
}
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    CreateGrid();
});
```

Please help me

Best regard

Answer (score 0):

Your responce text is wrong:

```
"cell""["1","Desktop","Desktop Description","200"]
```

this should be (note the : instead of " after the "cell" declaration):

```
"cell":["1","Desktop","Desktop Description","200"]
```

.. as the blank row you enter last, it is correct:

```
"cell":["","","",""]
```

also avoid using " in values, you should replace them with somethign other because some browsera cannot handle " escaping ... IE 6 ... :))

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but your code have so many errors, that it is difficult to describe all together. The first error in the JSON data with the quote (`"`) instead of `:`. The data after the modification will be

```
{
    "total": 2,
    "page": 5,
    "record": 10,
    "row": [
        {"i": 0,"cell": ["1","Desktop","Desktop Description","200"]},
        {"i": 1,"cell": ["2","Laptop","Laptop Description","1000"]},
        {"i": 2,"cell": ["2","DVD","DVD Description","100"]},
        {"i": 3,"cell": ["","","",""]} 
    ]
}
```

where you have data like `"i": 2` instead of `"id": 2`.

In the list of JavaScript files included in the `<head>` element you have full chaos. You included jqGrid more as once JavaScript files in compressed and uncompressed form. Moreover you used wrong order of files: you must include jquery-1.4.2.min.js before jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js which use it and include grid.locale-en.j before jquery.jqGrid.min.js. The file grid.loader.js by the way include all developer version of the files one more time. Moreover you should include in the head the meta element like `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` (see [example](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid#html_file)).

You should read the [How to Install](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:how_to_install) part of the documentation, decide which version of jqGrid (compressed or developer version) you want to use and include it.

**UPDATED**: I could continue with the list of errors. The main JavaScript file app.grid.js is written also very dirty. It contain clear errors like `type: "'POST'"` instead of `type: 'POST'` or `type: "POST"`, use `eval` function instead of `JSON.parse` and so on.

The usage of ashx to provide the data I find also not the best idea. Much better can be used ASMX web service, svc WCF service or ASP.NET MVC application with controller returns JSON data. Look at my [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029909/load-data-from-webservice-asmx-to-jqgrid-please-help-me/4031603#4031603) where you will find some links to examples to working code.

The usage of both `jQuery(function($) {/**/}` and `jQuery(document).ready(function() {/**/});` in the same code is also not good.

I recommend you to verify the JSON data in http://www.jsonlint.com/ and verify your JavaScript code in http://www.jslint.com/.