# Is jQGrid asp.net mvc version free?

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

Went through many links, but its still confusing.

As per my understanding. The jQGrid javascript version is free. While asp.net mvc version is not free..

Am i right?

Please provide information

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are **two different products**: free open source JavaScript jQuery plugin and commercial product [jqSuite](http://www.trirand.net/). Some editions of jqSuite have the same name jqGrid (see [here](http://www.trirand.net/licensing.aspx) and [here](http://www.trirand.net/download.aspx)). The product jqSuite uses  free open source JavaScript jQuery plugin internally. So it's "on top solution" based on the free jqGrid.

In general you don't really require to order jqSuite if you just need to include jqGrid in your ASP.NET project. The demos from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9349688/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10871428/315935) and many other show how you can implement it.

Another free solution is [Lib.Web.Mvc](https://github.com/tpeczek/Lib.Web.Mvc) (see [here](http://tpeczek.codeplex.com/releases/view/62741) the demos) developed by [tpeczek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/333253/tpeczek).

On the other side the usage of [jqSuite](http://www.trirand.net/) could improve your productivity.

Look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2736334/315935) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4439755/315935) for some additional information.

Comment: The was a spelling in Lib.Web.Mvc link - I've fixed that.

Comment: @tpeczek: Thank you Tomasz! You know such links sure better as any other person. :-)

Comment: I'm very happy that you know them :)