# ASP.NET MVC 4 Datagrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcgrid

Im new to ASP.NET MVC and want to do a simple page that retrieves some data using Entity and displays it in a paging datagrid.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or to a tutorial etc.

Its just a proof of concept for retrieving a list of stuff and displaying it.

Comment: I've done that, can't find a simple datagrid example with MVC 4, razor views etc, there are lots of old examples, but I want something new. But if your google skills are better than mine, feel free to share.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For that you can use ASP.NET MVC **jqGrid**.

Below I have mentioned **sample code** for how to achieve that.

**Sample Image**

[image]

**Action Method**

```
public ActionResult JsonSalesCollection(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate,
string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)

 {
     SalesLogic logicLayer = new SalesLogic();
     List<Sale> context;

     // If we aren't filtering by date, return this month's contributions
     if (startDate == DateTime.MinValue || endDate == DateTime.MinValue)
      {
         context = logicLayer.GetSales();
      }
     else // Filter by specified date range
      {
          context = logicLayer.GetSalesByDateRange(startDate, endDate);
      }

     // Calculate page index, total pages, etc. for jqGrid to us for paging
     int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
     int pageSize = rows;
     int totalRecords = context.Count();
     int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);

     // Order the results based on the order passed into the method
     string orderBy = string.Format("{0} {1}", sidx, sord);
     var sales = context.AsQueryable()
                  .OrderBy(orderBy) // Uses System.Linq.Dynamic library for sorting
                  .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
                  .Take(pageSize);

      // Format the data for the jqGrid
      var jsonData = new
       {
         total = totalPages,
         page = page,
         records = totalRecords,
         rows = (
                from s in sales
                select new
                {
                   i = s.Id,
                   cell = new string[] {
                   s.Id.ToString(),
                   s.Quantity.ToString(),
                   s.Product,
                   s.Customer,
                   s.Date.ToShortDateString(), 
                   s.Amount.ToString("c")
                }
           }).ToArray()
          };

         // Return the result in json
         return Json(jsonData);
}
```

**Jquery Set up**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var gridDataUrl = '/Home/JsonSalesCollection';
// use date.js to calculate the values for this month
var startDate = Date.parse('today').moveToFirstDayOfMonth();
var endDate = Date.parse('today');

jQuery("#list").jqGrid({

     url: gridDataUrl + '?startDate=' + startDate.toJSONString() + '&endDate=' +        endDate.toJSONString(),
     datatype: "json",
     mtype: 'GET',
     colNames: ['Sale Id', 'Quantity', 'Product', 'Customer', 'Date', 'Amount'],
     colModel: [
                  { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 50, align: 'left' },
                  { name: 'Quantity', index: 'Quantity', width: 100, align: 'left' },
                  { name: 'Product', index: 'Product', width: 100, align: 'left' },
                  { name: 'Customer', index: 'Customer', width: 100, align: 'left' },
                  { name: 'Date', index: 'Date', width: 100, align: 'left' },
                  { name: 'Amount', index: 'Amount', width: 100, align: 'right'}],
     rowNum: 20,
     rowList: [10, 20, 30],
     imgpath: gridimgpath,
     height: 'auto',
     width: '700',
     pager: jQuery('#pager'),
     sortname: 'Id',
     viewrecords: true,
     sortorder: "desc",
     caption: "Sales"
});

</script>
```

You can get more details from [**GridView in ASP.NET MVC Here**](http://www.schnieds.com/2010/01/gridview-in-aspnet-mvc.html)

### OR

Check This [**Get the Most out of WebGrid in ASP.NET MVC**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx) (compatible with MVC 4)

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: How about some indentation?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes. Actually formatting is the very annoying thing with SOF Editor.So, can't you suggest SOF to give us a better Editor ?.Any way I did it.I feel now it looks good.Check that.

Comment: Was looking for an MVC 4 example, razor views etc.

Comment: @DaleFraser yes you can apply this for mvc 4 razor views also.This does not depends on the mvc version.You can apply it for any version. Pure jquery. This jqGrid having lot of features.So you can customize it according to your situation very easily.I have mentioned a link also for more information.source code also there.Try it.If you having any problem please let me know.

Comment: @DaleFraser when we consider MVC development this is the best practice for handling things on client side.It's not like classical web forms.There having lot of server side controls.But MVC it's different.So try to do things in client side by using jquery as a client side library.

Comment: @DaleFraser I have updated another link on my post.Check that.http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ta/csharpgeneral/thread/cc08073d-caf1-4f66-af3d-148b51a63840

Comment: In the demo, `#list` is `<table id="list" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>`.

Comment: nice example.  there are so many client side tools available now.  developers are drifting away from server side tools.

Comment: @a.boussema Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506179/is-jqgrid-asp-net-mvc-version-free

Comment: @Sampath what `#pager` should be?

Comment: @IamnotBatman You can see that if you download the project by using above mentioned url.Please go ahead and do that.

Answer (score 6):

1. [`ASP.net MVC Awesome - jQuery Ajax helpers`](https://awesome.codeplex.com/) ([demo](http://demo.aspnetawesome.com/GridDemo))
   [image: ASP.net MVC Awesome grid]
2. [`jqxGrid`](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm?%28arctic%29#demos/jqxgrid/filterrow.htm)
   [image: jqxGrid]
3. [`Grid.MVC`](http://gridmvc.azurewebsites.net/) ([codeplex](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/)) sorting, paging, filtering
   [image: Grid.MVC demo]
4. [`MVCContrib.Grid`](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid)
5. [`jqGrid`](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) ([demo](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/))
   [image: jqGrid]
6. [`FuelUX repeater`](http://getfuelux.com/javascript.html#repeater)
   [image: fuelux repeater demo]
7. [`IgniteUI Grid`](http://igniteui.com/grid/feature-chooser)
   [image: IgniteUI Grid]