# Client-side binding of a datagrid to List<>

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, datagrid

In my ASP.NET MVC Webb app, I want a page to hold a DataGrid with ButtonColumns. To this I have a List<> of items that I want to represent in the DataGrid. By use of a textbox, I want the app (on the client side) to search the List<> for items matching the text string (preferably with LINQ).

What does this really require? Can this be done simply with Javascript? Do I need AJAX?

Does anyone here have experience with this kind of solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to at least attempt something.

Comment: Well. The question is really about what "platform" to use. Since I really don't know if this can be done with Javascript, or something of the likes, I really dont have much to attempt!


I'm not asking for a code solution. Just some advice as to where to begin.


I'm really not a web programmer, but rather a Windows programmer. That's where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a ViewModel of your List. Have a Grid on your view. You can use JavaScript&AJAX or post back to filter the grid. Most grids have filters built in.

I suggest you start on a MVC tutorial to get you started.

See [ASP.NET MVC 4 Datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079003/asp-net-mvc-4-datagrid)

Comment: Well. I know about the Model and the View. But for example. Can Javascript access the DataGrid and the List? Probably stupid questions. But I'm not very knowledgable about the gap between Javascript and C#/.NET.

Comment: JavaScript can access the grid and the ViewModel, yes. Go through some tutorials.

Comment: All right. This what really what I was looking for! Thanks!

Ajax is not needed for this then!