# Dynamic Generation of Grid for MVC ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress, spreadsheet, devexpress-mvc

I have posted similar question, but now I am re-posting it with more clear information about the problem I am dealing with.

I am transforming an existing application to a web based that is operating dynamically. It has grid consuming data from SQL table in such a way :

1. Columns can be added and deleted on runtime. (These columns are separated and shown as ListItem before showing the Grid on separate control, and user selects the columns for defining a Grid to have)
2. Column grouping can be done dynamically.
3. Custom settings can be defined for this Grid ( e.g
   On runtime , when each row gets data completed,  next row's few
   mandatory columns get last row's those cell values automatically and
   so on....)

and the whole Grid containing data for 10000's of objects must not disturb apart from the changes user can make.

I have searched a lot over the internet, I don't think so for complying all above requirements anz solution among ( qGrid, DevExpress or TelerikGrid ) would work. As DevExpress GridView can not be operated dynamically in this way.

What about SpreadSheet? Does this problem can be better solve able by DevExpress Spreadsheet control? In that case, still defining these configurations would be a problem? These configurations can be saved/altered for specific data objects ( Currently, these configurations are saved as seperate table and are being referenced for specific data set ).

What are the possible solutions to approach this scanario? ( SpreadSheet  ? )

Regards
Usman

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC 4 Datagrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079003/asp-net-mvc-4-datagrid)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177275/grid-controls-for-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Mick :  Perhaps you did not understood my requirements or not read question properly.
I am dealing with configurations of adding/removing columns when the Grid has already rendered. Already rendered Grid has no knowledge how many new column user can add ( might be some new extra column can be defined later on) and upon selection of those whole Grid can be re-rendered again with the new column while keeping 100's of object loaded data intact.

Comment: Your provided grids have no capability to be operated dynamically in this way. jqGrid and other Grids knew after rendering that how many/which columns it has. User can select any one later on by right clicking on its header and can group as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901210/is-there-a-full-working-example-for-a-jqgrid-columnchooser

Comment: Seems to work...

http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooser5__.htm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687201/jqgrid-column-chooser-modal-overlay/9688942#9688942