# Jqgrid license (with MIT/GPL v2) Vs Guriddo jqGrid JS (Creative Commons License)

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-inlinenav

I am using jqGrid  4.5.4 version in my development Env for a website application 
and want to use the same version when I publish my the application in commercial website.

My doubt is, recently I saw The latest version of Guriddo Jqgrid 4.7.1 and its New license
Creative Commons License.

please tell me can I use the Jqgrid Version 4.5.4(under MIT/GPL License) in commercial website now?

Can I use Jqgrid versions prior 4.7 are with MIT/GPL v2 license in commercial website now?

Answer (score 11):

You can sure continue to use 4.5.4, 4.6 or 4.7 in your commercial website under MIT/GPL License. The versions 4.7.1 and 4.7 are practically identical (see all the differences [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/compare/v4.7.0...v4.7.1)). You can download from [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/releases/tag/v4.7.0) the 4.7.0 version and  see [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/grid.base.js#L5-L9) with the license agreement. You can compare there with [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/minified/jquery.jqGrid.min.js#L2-L6) of minimized file of jqGrid 4.6. The version 4.7.0 was published Dec 8, 2014. Some days later Tony have changed the licence and published 4.7.1 Dec 16, 2014.

So you are can use all versions up to 4.7.0 under MIT/GPL License.

MIT License *allows to make changes in the code*. So everybody can modify the code of 4.7.0 and provide the results under MIT/GPL License for free.

For example I made a lot of changes. You can download the corresponding code from [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). I plan to create the corresponding documentation and to publish new free version of jqGrid under the name "free jqGrid" very soon. You can see the preliminary version of the docuemtation [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html).

**UPDATE**: It's published currently two release versions of free jqGrid: [4.8.0](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/tree/v4.8.0) and [4.9.0](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/tree/v4.9.0) which included many new features and improvements. As the documentation you can use many [wiki articles](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki). I will use 4.x.y conversion for the version numbers, because I want to hold the compatibility to the old 4.x versions of jqGrid. I still hope to find the time for writing more detailed documentation. :-)

I published release versions of free jqGrid on two public CDNs: [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/free-jqgrid) and [jsDelivr](http://www.jsdelivr.com/#!free-jqgrid). So everybody can use the corresponding URLs in you projects. One can use additionally the URL to the latest sources from GitHub like it's described [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs#access-githib-code-from-rawgit), but I recommend don't used it in production.

I published free jqGrid additionally on three well knows repositories: [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid/) (use `Install-Package free-jqGrid` to install), [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/free-jqgrid) (use `npm install free-jqgrid` to install) and [bower](http://bower.io/search/?q=free-jqgrid) (use `bower install free-jqgrid` to install).

I hope that all above simplifies the usage of **free jqGrid** for everybody. Additionally I implements typically very quickly fixes for all bugs posted as [issue](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues). Everybody can scroll over [closed issues](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aclosed) to see the time of reaction on the reported problem. Please provide the demo which reproduce the problem, if it's possible, or post JavaScript code and the test case which can I use to reproduce the reported problem. I hope I could hold the same quick reaction time in the future too.

Comment: Your Contribution to JqGrid is commendable . Many Thanks :)

Comment: WOW. Men It will be great. If it will be still developed under MIT/GPL license.

Comment: @masterdany88: You are welcome! I post some changes to [github](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), improvements or new features almost every day. I hope to publish the next version (4.9) in the next month (in Mai). I hope that I will find time to write new documentation additionally to [wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki).