# which jqGrid version I can use without breaking license?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

my client not allow to use any commercial S/W without huge list of approvals.
can you please suggest which jqGrid plugin version we can use without breaking any license?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439650/is-jqgrid-free

Comment: @Akki619: [The answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4439755/315935) is not more actual. [Another one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28530747/315935) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30438601/315935) provides the answer about license of jqGrid forks.

Comment: Thank you Oleg and Akki619 for your quick response.

Comment: I like to use Oleg free jqGrid but I got three problems with it, would you please let me know what i'm doing wrong.
1 when I try to add/edit a record on the grid, add or edit form keeps on relocating to the new position for every open and close.
2) After selecting record for edit, edit form navigation to other records in a grid is not working
3) when I open a "add record"  form and try to close it with out entering data, it still prompting for save changes.

Comment: @GuruN: Could you provide the demo which reproduces the problems described above. Please use URLs to jQuery, jQuery UI and free jqGrid from common source. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/hasSubrgid.htm) for the code example. You can post new question which describes the problem and the exact steps for reproducing or you can post [new issue](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues) in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) repository on GitHub. All problems which can be reproduced, debugged and solved very quickly. Please use "@Oleg" in comments.