# jqGrid - Free License

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

All,
I was actively using jqGrid in the past few years, now I need it back to work on a requirement. Looks like the name has been changed to Gurrido JQGrid and seems to be a licensed version.

Could you please let me know if I no longer can use jqgrid for commercial purposes? 
At lease can I use the previous version of jqGrid? Please let me know..

Thanks!

Update  : pasting the code snippet

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submitbutton1").click(function(){
    jQuery("#listTable").jqGrid({
        url:'/WebTest/MainAction.do',
       datatype: "json",
                colNames: ['Label','Value'],
                colModel: [
                    {name:'label',index:'label'},
                    {name:'value',index:'value'} 
                ],
                autowidth : true,
                //iconSet: "fontAwesome",
                //showOneSortIcon: true,
                //autoResizing: { compact: true, widthOfVisiblePartOfSortIcon: 13 },
                //autoresizeOnLoad: true,
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [5, 10, 20, "10000:All"],
                viewrecords: true,
                pager: true,
                toppager: true,
                rownumbers: true,
                sortname: "label",
                sortorder: "desc",
                caption: "Test"
            }).jqGrid("navGrid", { view: true, cloneToTop: true})
            .jqGrid("inlineNav")
            .jqGrid("filterToolbar")
            .jqGrid("gridResize");
   })
 })

</script>
```

```html
<html >
<head>
  
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" media="screen" href="../font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../css/ui.jqgrid.min.css" />
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../css/searchFilter.css" /> -->
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../css/ui.multiselect.css" /> -->
<script src="../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="../js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
 $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
</script>
<script src="../js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- Version took from free jqgrid github -->
</head>
<title>Test</title>
<body bgcolor="white">
<br>
Hi this is the Test file
<input type="button" name="submitbutton1"  id="submitbutton1" value="Test">  
<br/>
<div id="outerDiv" style="margin:5px;">
        <table id="list"></table>
        <!--<div id="pager"></div>-->
</div>

// Tried this also, but its the same. Please note I have removed the iconSet as well. 
<table id="listTable"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The picture looks like you used wrong CSS or you have some additional CSS rule from outer div of grid which will be applied of grid and where you have some problems.

Comment: Do you have `<!DOCTYPE html>` before `<html>`? You use `<title>Test</title>` on the wrong place. It's strictly recommended to include `<meta charset="utf-8">` and `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` at the beginning of `<head>`. Where you placed `<script>` with the code? Which version of jqGrid you used before? I recommend to verify your HTML code in http://validator.w3.org/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can't change the license of previously published versions of jqGrid. So if you loaded once the code which have "Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses" comment inside then you can use it under the licenses.

All versions of jqGrid till (inclusive) 4.7 can be used for free under MIT or GPLv2 licenses. You can download it from [github](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/tree/v4.7.0) (see the license statement [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/minified/jquery.jqGrid.min.js#L2-L7)).

The version 4.7.1 published short time after publishing of 4.7 have new license. Starting with 4.7.1 it's better to use another name: "Guriddo jqGrid JS" for the product. You can read [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) more about the price and the conditions of Guriddo jqGrid JS.

MIT and GPLv2 licenses allows to *modify* the code holding the reference to the author of the previous version used as basis. So I started new fork of jqGrid based on jqGrid 4.7 under the name **free jqGrid**. One can download it from github [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). [The readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md) and [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) provide additional information about new features which I implemented. I published the first release 4.8 of free jqGrid at 4 Mar 2015. I provided the version over [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid), [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/free-jqgrid) and [bower](http://bower.io/search/?q=free-jqgrid) additionally to the way to download the sources directly from [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). I posted the code additionally to different CDNs (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)) to simplify the usage.

I plan to publish very soon free jqGrid 4.9. I'll post the beta version in next days, but you can use the version from githib at any time. It includes always `jquery.jqgrid.min.js`, `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` and `jquery.jqgrid.min.map` generated from the current code.

So you can use free jqGrid for free like the name already says. I ask only to report the bugs as github [issue](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues) or to post it on the stackoverflow. Please use both tabs "jqgrid" and "free-jqgrid" if you post the question about free jqGrid on the stackoverflow.

By the way the wiki is opened for writing. So if somebody want to improve the text of existing articles of to post new one then you are welcome!

Comment: Thanks Oleg, I know I will surely get a response from you :)  I have just downloaded the entire ZIP version from - [link](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) . So I can go ahead and use this version. I believe its the free jqgrid 4.8? I opted for your version as I know there will be upgrades to it in further as well rather than the earlier 4.7.1

Comment: @Faz: The version available from [the link](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) is already **free jqGrid 4.9 beta - the latest code**. It contains many new features and performance improvements. I tried to hold it the mostly compatible with the previous versions of jqGrid. So I hope that you can just replace the sources and it will already work. I recommend you to add Font Awesome directly at the beginning. You need just add `<link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="htps://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">` and add the option `iconSet: "fontAwesome"` (see wiki).

Comment: Thanks Oleg, I will try to check the wiki and add the fontAwesowe.. can't we use the jqgrid without this?

Comment: @Faz: Yes of case. Default icons are old non-scalable icons of jQuery UI.

Comment: Okie, I just added those stuffs and constructing a basic grid. I'm hitting a strange issue, where in the GRID is displayed vertically i.e; all columns, pagers are aligned in a vertical fashion... btw, am using jquery-1.11.1.js . And trying this sample [link](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/navButtons0-fa4_custom_.htm)

Comment: @Faz: **Which version of jqGrid you used before?** Could you provide the demo which shows what you do? What you need is just to replace URLs to CSS and two JS files. You can use the original files from GitHub for the first test (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs#access-githib-code-from-rawgit)).

Comment: I have attached the image in the question for your reference.. Also, I did similar stuffs that you mentioned, but not sure whats wrong here..

Comment: @Faz: One can't debug the image and to look which other CSS will be applied on the header. :-) Do you have a link to your demo which can demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Exactly I was trying to get to that. Its a simple html page, is there a way I can share it wit you?

Comment: @Faz: I'm not sure what you use typically. You can append full HTML page starting with `<!doctype html>` to the text of your question. You can use [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for example to provide working code. I recommend you to use direct URLs from GitHub in the first test like [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs#access-githib-code-from-rawgit). If you loads local files then you need use `http:` or `https:` prefix to all URLs

Comment: pasted the code for your review.. There was a typo with autowidth, I changed it now but for some reasons, I see a problem with the pager element.. as adding pager element,I see it is taking more width than it should take.

Comment: additionally I tried to check the runtime UI and notice that I see a height of 100% for ui-pg-table under the **div id="jqg1"**

Comment: @Faz: Sorry, but you should provide *real demo* which you use. I don't understand which dialect of HTML you want to use. I posted many comments about `<!doctype html>` before `<html>` and asked you multiple time about previous version of jqGrid which you used, but you don't answer.  You use once `<br/>` another time `<br>` and `<input type="button" name="submitbutton1"  id="submitbutton1" value="Test">` (no closing of `<input>` tag). Can you move `<table id="listTable"></table>` directly at the beginning of `<body>` to eliminate the side effects of non-closed tags?

Comment: My bad, dint notice that I was using struts-html tag and that was conflicting. Now its fine.. Thanks for your help.. BTW, sorry to get in another Qusetion....I'm using the datatype as 'json', wont the filterOption work on the fly with the data that's already loaded on the UI.. does the loadOnce work out for this?

Comment: @Faz: First of all the correct name of the option to loading the data at once is: `loadonce: true`. I use the same case of all existing options to hold the compatibility. You should better to open new question where you describe your new problem in details.

Comment: As mentioned, I have opened a new question --> [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444865/)