# My Development application using JQgrid 4.6.0 version but current jqgrid is not free for commercial license

Tags: jqgrid

I have developed my web application using Jqgrid 4.6.0 version which is in MIT license. 
Is it ok if i use same version ( 4.6.0) commercially by publishing my web app.
I don't want to use latest Jqgrid version as the 4.6.0 version is sufficient for me.

What are the steps to take to avoid any legal issue if i use 4.6.0 version.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [questions about licensing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/369450) are off-topic. Licensing questions [may be on-topic at Programmers.SE](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7265/69573).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All versions of jqGrid inclusive version 4.7.0 was published under dual licensed: the MIT and GPLv2. Once published, the license agreement can't be changes *for the version*. Thus you can still use it commercially free of charge. Moreover the licenses allows everybody to modify the code if required. One should just not remove the copyright remark inserted by the author.

You should hold new licence agreement of Guriddo jqGrid JS if you use the version 4.7.1, 4.8, 4.8.1, 4.8.2, 5.0.0, 5.0.1. In the case you should pay the charge, described [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334).

Correspond to the MIT license I made the fork of jqGrid 4.7.0 about one year ago, fixed many small bugs existing in jqGrid 4.6/4.7 and implemented many new features. I publish the product under the name **free jqGrid** on [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). All the published versions (4.8.0, 4.9.0, 4.9.1, 4.9.2, 4.10.0, 4.11.0, 4.11.0 and the current 4.12.0) are available on CDNs (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)), npm, bower, NuGet and WebJars (see [the readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md)). I publish free jqGrid under the same dual licences MIT and GPLv2 like jqGrid 4.6 which you use now. I just ask to contribute the development by donating via PayPal, if one have the possibility for it (see [the readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md)).

Thus you can either continue to use jqGrid 4.6 or to consider to upgrade to free jqGrid 4.12.0. The most advantage of migration is the usage of *alive* version. You can report any bug, which you could find, or to post suggestion of new feature as [an issue](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues) on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your contribution to Free-JqGrid. it really saving our time. I will try to use in my app and see how it works.

Comment: but initially There was a Jqgrid for MVC using C# code  from Trirand. I did not find in GitHub. What is the differennce between Jqgrid MVC and your Free -Jqgrid

Comment: @SanjaySanjay: Jqgrid for MVC using C# is *commercial* product, which seems be not developed more. I don't find the implementation as correct way. First of all one can use `loadonce: true` in the most scenarios. If one need to display less as for example 1000 rows, then `loadonce: true` will be the best way. One will have very simple C# code which just provides JSON with the data. The examples of the implementation of server side paging and filtering are free available too. Thus I don't see any reason for jqGrid MVC. Probably just good examples of some scenarios.

Comment: is jqgrid-bootstrap.css available for free jqGrid? if yes please provied

Comment: @SanjaySanjay: Free jqGrid has no `jqgrid-bootstrap.css`. Instead of it the CCS styles from `ui.jqgrid.css` are changed so that it works in the same way if you add Bootstrap.css or not.