# This is a trial version of jqGrid for ASP.NET MVC which has expired

Tags: jqgrid

I have recently been upgrading a legacy application from MVC4 to MVC5 and I discovered that I can no longer use my version of JqGrid. I get the message;

```
This is a trial version of jqGrid for ASP.NET MVC which has expired.
```

I found out that I can still get a free version;
[Is JQGrid free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439650/is-jqgrid-free)
So I uninstall the existing JqGrid via Nuget and I download the new free version via Nuget: `Install-Package free-jqGrid`
I run the application but I still get the "trial version" error message. I try clearing the caches but still I have this problem. How do I fix this?

Comment: You use probably "jqSuite ASP.NET MVC" or "jqGrid ASP.NET MVC" from http://www.trirand.net/. I'm not sure why you could need the product. It could be helpful only for people who absolutely don't know JavaScript and who have problems to write MVC Action which return JSON data. One can just use standard acttions in MVC5 which return JSON and write short JavaScript code which uses free jqGrid, which read the data and fill in the grid. No additional "jqSuite ASP.NET MVC" would be required.

Comment: Yes, so the problem was that I was using a Trirand dll for MVC which is no longer available for free. I need to replicate the code in JavaScript and I am looking for documentation to do that, in particular example code for toolbar searching.

Comment: How many rows of data needed be displayed? If it's less as 1000 or 10000 then I would recommend you to use `loadonce: true, forceClientSorting: true` options. Then the server need just return **all the data** and the client need just call `filterToolbar`. See [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#filtering). [One more demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-4000-20-free-jqgrid.htm) can be used to test the performance of local sorting, paging and filtering of 4000 rows, 13 columns and 20 rows/page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that the Trirand dll for "jqGrid ASP.NET MVC" is no longer available for free.
The best option is to use the free version of JqGrid in javascript, which works perfectly well enough.