# JQGrid free version

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

There are **multiple versions** of ***JQGrid*** available. Could any one please highlight which is **free** because my initial understanding was that it was totally free?

There is **CDN version** available too.

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.2/jquery.jqgrid.min.js

Another link related to JQGrid is.

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition

The other version is **[Gurido](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/)**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is JQGrid free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439650/is-jqgrid-free)

Comment: I agree that the question is duplicate. Guriddo is **commercial** product. You can see the licence agreement and the prices [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). I develop and provide the product under the name "free jqGrid" under old MIT and GPL licenses **completely free of charge**. Both "Guriddo jqGrid JS" and "free jqGrid" have the same starting point "jqGrid" 4.7, but both was developed independently since the end of 2014 and contains different features. You can find [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/index.html) short introduction and in the wiki and READMEs more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is duplicate of [the old one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439650/is-jqgrid-free). Nevertheless I decide to write one more answer with some new/additional information.

Guriddo jqGrid JS is **commercial** product. You can see the licence agreement and the prices [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). I develop and provide the product under the name ["free jqGrid"](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) under old MIT and GPL licenses **completely free of charge**. Both "Guriddo jqGrid JS" and "free jqGrid" have the same starting point "jqGrid" 4.7, but both was developed independently since the end of 2014 and contains different features. Both can be interpreted as forks of "jqGrid" 4.7 product. You can find [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/index.html) short introduction and in [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) and [READMEs](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) more details.

Both products ("Guriddo jqGrid JS" and "free jqGrid") have different goals. I provides "free jqGrid" for free and thus it's natural, that I publish it on different public places starting with the first version (4.8). The recommended way of the usage is from CDNs. One can choose [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/free-jqgrid) or [jsDelivr](https://www.jsdelivr.com/projects/free-jqgrid) or CDNs, which wrap npm or GitHup packages. [The wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) describe mode detailed how "free jqGrid" can be loaded from CDNs.

Additionally "free jqGrid" is available from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid) and on [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfree-jqgrid) and as [bower](https://bower.io/search/?q=free-jqgrid) package.

I don't find enough time to create the site with good documentation, but I try to hold maximal compatibility with old jqGrid 4.x and thus [old jqGrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs) can be used. [Here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) I publish short introduction about the usage of free jqGrid. If one uses TypeScript or at least understand it's syntax then [free-jqgrid.d.ts](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/ts/free-jqgrid.d.ts) would be good source, which describes all existing options, methods and events supported by "free jqGrid".

Comment: Thanks for the response. Much appreciated. So below mentioned CDN is a free version?
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.2/jquery.jqgrid.min.js

Comment: @FIrePanda: You are welcome! You use wrong terminology "a free version". "Free jqGrid" and "Guriddo jqGrid JS" are name of the product. "Free jqGrid" can be used for free under MIT/GPL licenses. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.2/jquery.jqgrid.min.js is one file, which belong to free jqGrid. It has to be used together with `ui.jqgrid.min.css`. See [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#the_first_grid_code) an example.