# Add Paging for JqGrid

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

am trying to add jQuery Grid into my application(C# and Asp.net) using samples provided in some blogs, able to use Json data sent by Webservice.
Now have tried to add pagination for the Grid and got strucked.Script is like this.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#table").jqGrid({
            datatype: function (pdata) { getData(pdata); },
            height: 250,
            colNames: ['ID', 'First Name', 'Last Name'],
            colModel: [
            { name: 'ID', width: 60, sortable: false },
            { name: 'FirstName', width: 200, sortable: false },
            { name: 'LastName', width: 200, sortable: false }
        ],

            imgpath: '<%= ResolveClientUrl("styles/redmon/images") %>',

            pager: jQuery('#pager'),
            rowNum: 2,
            rowList: [2, 5, 10, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000],                
            height: "100%",
            viewrecords: true,
            scrollOffset: 0,
            caption: 'Sample'

        });
    });
    function getData(pData) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/WebService.asmx/GetListOfPersons") %>',
            data: '{}',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                if (textStatus == "success")
                    ReceivedClientData(JSON.parse(getMain(data)).rows);
            },
            error: function (data, textStatus) {
                alert('An error has occured retrieving data!');
            }
        });
    }
    function ReceivedClientData(data) {
        var thegrid = $("#table");
        thegrid.clearGridData();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            thegrid.addRowData(i + 1, data[i]);
    }
    function getMain(dObj) {
        if (dObj.hasOwnProperty('d'))
            return dObj.d;
        else
            return dObj;
    }
</script>
```

...html block

```
     <table id="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
</table>
<div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>
```

The Pager div is displayed and attached but isnt working am I missing something?

Thanks 
Samuel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You main problem is that you ignore the `pData` of the `getData` which can be forwarded to your ASMX web service.

You use very **old template** for your jqGrid. The current version of jqGrid now 4.3 and you use still `imgpath` which was already deprecated in the version 3.5 (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:upgrade_from_3.4.x_to_3.5#options)). Very old version of jqGrid had no good support for calling of Web services, but even at the time one could already use `addJsonData` and `addXmlData` methods to add the data more effectively as you do with respect of `addRowData`. It is documented [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#function).

I recommend you better instead of modifying of `getData` function use `datatype: 'json'` instead of `datatype` as function. In [the old demo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3161542/315935) for example you can find an example how to implement this exactly. In [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3170652/315935) you can find an example how to use `loadonce: true` parameter in case if you prefer don't implement data paging on the server and instead of that want send all the grid data to the client side and allow jqGrid do paging, sorting and  filtering the data for you on the client side. It can work effective only with relatively small number of rows (some hundred rows for example).

**UPDATED**: If you use `SqlDataReader` to get the data from the database you can construct the SQL statement (`SqlCommand`) base on the `rows` and `page` parameters which you receive from the server.

In the most cases you need query the data which has unique ids. So you can implement paging using of `SELECT TOP` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` construction. Let us I explain it on an example. For example you need to query Product with the price from the `dbo.Products` table of the [Northwind](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23654) database. To get first page of data you can use

```sql
SELECT TOP(10) ProductID, ProductName, UnitPrice FROM dbo.Products
```

where `10` you should replace to the value of the `rows` parameter. To get another page defined by parameter `page` you need skip `(page-1)*rows` items and get the next top `page` items. Using [common table expression (CTE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) syntax you can write the statement vary easy:

```sql
WITH GetAll (Id,ProductName,UnitPrice) AS (
    SELECT ProductID,ProductName,UnitPrice FROM dbo.Products
), GetTop (Id,ProductName,UnitPrice) AS (
    SELECT TOP(20) * FROM GetAll
), GetNext (Id,ProductName,UnitPrice) AS (
    SELECT TOP(10) a.* FROM GetAll AS a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN GetTop AS t ON t.Id = a.Id
    WHERE t.Id IS NULL
)
SELECT * FROM GetNext
```

You should just replace `10` and `20` on two places above to `rows` and `(page-1)*rows`. If you has some database which not support common table expression (CTE) you can rewrite the same query with respect of subqueries:

```
SELECT TOP(10) a.* FROM (SELECT ProductID,ProductName,UnitPrice FROM dbo.Products)
        AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN
            (SELECT TOP(20) ProductID,ProductName,UnitPrice FROM dbo.Products) AS t
                ON t.ProductID = a.ProductID
WHERE t.ProductID IS NULL
```

Comment: Hi,Oleg thanks for the quick response. Yes Was using version 3.5. 1 up for explainig the differences between two versions. Also, could you please provide a sample link for Server side pagination?

Comment: @Samuel: In any way I strictly recommend you [download](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) the last version of jqGrid. The implementation of the paging depend on the technology which you use on the server side. Do you use Entity Framework, LINQ to SQL or `SqlDataReader` for example?

Comment: Oleg,I use SqlDataReader. Have downloaded version 4.2 and am trying to get some logic to implement server side paging as notified by you for large datasets.

Comment: @Samuel: I updated my answer with an example how you can construct the SQL statements based on `page` and `rows` parameter which get your web server as parameters from jqGrid (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3161542/315935) an example)

Comment: Thanks a  lot Oleg, Finally It worked.Your provided links and the above explanation is so clear and straight forward.Thanks a Lot again.

Comment: @Samuel: You are welcome! I'am glad to know that I could help you.

Comment: Hi Oleg,Sorry to trouble you one more time, am using JqGrid 4.2 version with jquery 1.5.2 .. There is an exception being caught every time at this line of jquery 1.5.2 finally {     fired = [ context, args ];       firing = 0;} ..any reasons which you ever faced?

Comment: @Samuel: In the most cases the reason of exception the the wrong order of included JavaScript files. Verify the order based on [the example](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid#html_file). For troubleshooting I recommend you to use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`. Moreover it would be better to use JqGrid 4.3, jQuery 1.7.1 and jQuery UI 1.8.17 or 1.8.16. If you would have problems you can open new question and include full HTML and JavaScript code which can be used to reproduce the problem. Try to reduce the example if it's possible.

Comment: Sorry Just Realized No need to load jquery-1.5.2.js only jquery-1.5.2-min.js is needed for jqgrid.