# First Jqgrid Load, sorting and filtering slow in IE6. Filtering slow in the rest of Browsers

Tags: sorting, jqgrid, load, filtering

I'm facing this situation. I'm having a grid with approximately 3500 rows. And this grid should be cross-browsing, specially in IE6 (which is the Client's browser... unfortunately).

When I do the test in IE6, the loading takes so many time than other browsers. After seeing this, I've decided to optimize the query and now it's loading only the necessary db fields, but the loading in IE still slow. My datatype is `JSON`.

Besides this inconvenience, I've found that the filtering is slow in all the browsers (in IE6 takes so much more time than others). I'm using in the filter the option `searchOnEnter : false`, Sorting by a column in IE6 is slow as well.

What can I do to decrease the loading time and when I use the filtering and sorting by a column? I'm still surfing trying to get a possible solution but I'm running out of ideas.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**: jQGrid Code

```
var myGrid = $('#bookingsList');
myGrid.jqGrid({
    jsonReader : { root: "rows", repeatitems: false, id: "0", cell: ""},
    url:'/WebBooking/json/bookingListAct.action',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames:['Id','Site','CompanyId','Created'],
    colModel :[
    {name:'bestillingId', index:'bestillingId', width:45, sorttype: 'int'}, 
    {name:'stedName', index:'stedName', width:90},
    {name:'firmaId', index:'firmaId', width:200, hidden:true}, 
    {name:'creationDate', index:'creationDate', width:105, search:false}
    ],
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,50,100,150,200,250,500],
    sortname: 'bestillingId',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    loadonce: true,
    sortable: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    autoencode: true,
    ignoreCase: true,
    shrinkToFit:false,
    width: 1050,
    height: '100%'
});
```

**UPDATE**: JSON String (A Portion)

`{"page":"1","records":"3180","rows":[{"stedName":"Mongstad","bestillingId":"2","firmaName":"Reinertsen AS","creationDate":"13.09.11 09:01"}],"total":"318"}`

Comment: You should always post the code of jqGrid which you use in such questions. The example of the JSON response from the server (with at least one row) is also helpful. You should understand that **details of implementation** and not the common description what you do is important in troubleshooting of performance questions. It sounds that you use `loadonce: true` and *client-side filtering*. Why you don't do this on the server? If you need support slow clients with very slow JavaScript engine like IE6 it's especially important.

Comment: @Oleg I've updated my question with the Code and the JSON response. Actually I'm using `loadonce:true`. About why I'm not filtering on the server is because honestly I didn't know that that option exists. If you're suggesting this as a possible solution, can you give me some examples of how I can make this filtering on the server? - at least the integration between the client side and server side - (I'm working with Java but no matters if the examples are in other languages). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem in your current code is the usage of `loadonce: true`. In the case the implementation of `url:'/WebBooking/json/bookingListAct.action'` is very easy: you returns just *all data* to the jqGrid. Nevertheless event in the case you should sort the data corresponds to `sortname: 'bestillingId'` and `sortorder: 'desc'` which will be seen on the server (in `bookingListAct.action`) as `sidx` and `sord` parameters.

You should understand that in case of usage `loadonce: true` the sorting, paging and filtering of data will be implemented on the client side in JavaScript code. How you know JavaScript is mostly interpreter and the code will be not compiled (at least in old web browsers). So sorting of data on the client side is many times (or many thousand times) slowly as on the server in the compiled native code. If you hold the data in the database and have indexes on the columns which you permit to sort or filter the sorting and filtering will be more quickly in the server side implementation.

So my main suggestion will be to implement **server-side sorting, paging and filtering**.

To implement sorting on the server side you should `sidx` and `sord` to construct `ORDER BY` in the corresponding SQL `SELECT` statement.

To implement paging on the server side you should use information from `page` and `rows` parameters. You can use `SELECT TOP` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or `LIMIT` and `SKIP` depend on the dialect of SQL which you use (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8480127/315935)) some details.

To implement filtering you should first use `stringResult: true` option of [filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching#calling_convention) to have information about the filters to be send in the Advanced Searching format (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching#options)). The full filter in form of JSON string will be send to the server as `filters` parameter. Additionally it will be send boolean `_search` parameter. On the server side you should convert `filters` parameter from JSON string to object and parse the information. Then you should use the information to construct `WHERE` part of the corresponding `SELECT` statement.

If all information sorting, paging and filtering are exist in the request to the server then you should first filter the data, sort the results and the get the requested page from the results. The `records` and `total` values in the server response should take in the consideration the filtering. So if the filtered data consists for example from 12 rows and the page size is 10 you should return `"records": 12, "total": 2` instead of `"records": 3180, "total": 318` which you have in unfiltered data.

I don't use Java myself. I am not sure whether it helps you but in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935) you will find and download Visual Studio C# project which implement paging, sorting and filtering.

The last remark. The row of data which you returns from the server currently looks like

```json
{"stedName":"Mongstad","bestillingId":"2","firmaName":"Reinertsen AS",
    "creationDate":"13.09.11 09:01"}
```

If you would use default `repeatitems: true` format of the data together with `id: "0", cell: ""` you can replace the data needed for the row to

```json
["Mongstad","2","Reinertsen AS",:"13.09.11 09:01"]
```

It will reduce the size of data and improve performance additionally. Moreover I personally don't like to use date in the form like `"13.09.11 09:01"`. Such form is localized, will be interpreted as string and so can't be correct sorted and filtered. It would be better to return data in [ISO 8601](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format format: `2011-109-13T08:01Z` or `2011-109-13T09:01+01:00`. You can use `formatter: 'data'` with `formatoptions: { srcformat: 'ISO8601Long', newformat: 'd.m.y H:i' }`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick but extensive response. I'm going to see this and trying to implement the sorting, filtering and paging by myself on the server side. I'll let you know in any case if this works in the end. Thanks again.

Comment: @ABottoni: You are welcome! You can start with sorting and paging for example and will see the difference in performance between sorting of 3500 rows on the server side and returning the first 10 rows of results and the same implementation of IE6. After the first part will be finished you can implement filtering.