# jqGrid - ASP.NET WebService JSON datasource showing up blank

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, jqgrid, asmx

I am coming up blank with an answer to why this isn't working.
Essentially the end result is a blank grid with no Javascript or XHR errors being thrown.

Javascript code:

```
var MyServiceURL = "MyService.asmx/";

function getOrders() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: MyServiceURL + 'GetOrders',
        success: function(data) {
            var thegrid = $("#orders")[0];
            thegrid.addJSONData(data);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            var error = $.parseJSON(e.responseText);
            $('#msg').html(error.Message);
        }
    });
}

function bindGrid() {
    $("#orders").jqGrid({
        datatype: getOrders,
        colNames: ['CO_ODNO', 'CO_STATUS', 'ROUTE_CODE', 'ROUTE_STOP', 'PRIOR_NAME', 'CU_NO'],
        colModel: [{ name: 'CO_ODNO', index: 'CO_ODNO', width: 200, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'CO_STATUS', index: 'CO_STATUS', width: 200, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'ROUTE_CODE', index: 'ROUTE_CODE', width: 200, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'ROUTE_STOP', index: 'ROUTE_STOP', width: 200, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'PRIOR_NAME', index: 'PRIOR_NAME', width: 200, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'CU_NO', index: 'CU_NO', width: 200, align: 'left' }
                   ],
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50, 100],
        sortname: 'CO_ODNO',
        pager: $('#pager'),
        sortorder: "desc",
        viewrecords: true
    });


}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajaxSetup({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{}",
        dataFilter: function(data) {
            var msg;

            if (typeof (JSON) !== 'undefined' &&
            typeof (JSON.parse) === 'function')
                msg = JSON.parse(data);
            else
                msg = eval('(' + data + ')');

            if (msg.hasOwnProperty('d'))
                return msg.d;
            else
                return msg;
        }
    });

    $('#btnGetOrders').click(function() {
        bindGrid();
    });

});
```

Data being returned from server (validated with JSON Lint):

```
{"d":"[{\"CO_ODNO\":\"1               \",\"CO_STATUS\":\"D\",\"ROUTE_CODE\":\"K&H \",\"ROUTE_STOP\":0,\"PRIOR_NAME\":\"\",\"CU_NO\":\"24105     \",\"SHIP_TO\":\"24105     \",\"ORDER_DT_TM\":\"\\/Date(1044635082000)\\/\",\"ORDER_REQD_DT\":\"\\/Date(1059624060000)\\/\",\"SHIP_REQD_DT\":\"\\/Date(1059624060000)\\/\",\"ORDER_TYPE\":\"LIC\",\"CARRIER\":\"\",\"TIMESTAMP\":\"\\/Date(1059572051000)\\/\",\"ORDER_DEL_DT\":\"\\/Date(1044635105000)\\/\",\"TRAFFIC_REF_NO\":\"\",\"SITE\":3,\"PALLET_CUBE\":-1,\"HOST_ODNO\":\"1\",\"CLI_NO\":\"\",\"SERVICE_LEVEL\":\"\",\"EMPLOYEE_NUMBER\":\"\",\"PAY_METHOD\":\"                \",\"CU_NAME\":\"\",\"PU_ORDER_FL\":\"Y\",\"DELIVERY_FL\":\"\",\"ENTRY_FL\":\"\"},{\"CO_ODNO\":\"100056          \",\"CO_STATUS\":\"D\",\"ROUTE_CODE\":\"\",\"ROUTE_STOP\":0,\"PRIOR_NAME\":\"\",\"CU_NO\":\"802977    \",\"SHIP_TO\":\"802977    \",\"ORDER_DT_TM\":\"\\/Date(1045755045000)\\/\",\"ORDER_REQD_DT\":\"\\/Date(1045803660000)\\/\",\"SHIP_REQD_DT\":\"\\/Date(1045803660000)\\/\",\"ORDER_TYPE\":\"LIC\",\"CARRIER\":\"\",\"TIMESTAMP\":\"\\/Date(1144859314000)\\/\",\"ORDER_DEL_DT\":\"\\/Date(1045777318000)\\/\",\"TRAFFIC_REF_NO\":\"\",\"SITE\":3,\"PALLET_CUBE\":-1,\"HOST_ODNO\":\"\",\"CLI_NO\":\"\",\"SERVICE_LEVEL\":\"\",\"EMPLOYEE_NUMBER\":\"\",\"PAY_METHOD\":\"                \",\"CU_NAME\":\"\",\"PU_ORDER_FL\":\"N\",\"DELIVERY_FL\":\"\",\"ENTRY_FL\":\"\"},{\"CO_ODNO\":\"100101          \",\"CO_STATUS\":\"D\",\"ROUTE_CODE\":\"\",\"ROUTE_STOP\":0,\"PRIOR_NAME\":\"\",\"CU_NO\":\"806821    \",\"SHIP_TO\":\"806821    \",\"ORDER_DT_TM\":\"\\/Date(1045760795000)\\/\",\"ORDER_REQD_DT\":\"\\/Date(1045803660000)\\/\",\"SHIP_REQD_DT\":\"\\/Date(1045803660000)\\/\",\"ORDER_TYPE\":\"LIC\",\"CARRIER\":\"\",\"TIMESTAMP\":\"\\/Date(1144859314000)\\/\",\"ORDER_DEL_DT\":\"\\/Date(1045777603000)\\/\",\"TRAFFIC_REF_NO\":\"\",\"SITE\":3,\"PALLET_CUBE\":-1,\"HOST_ODNO\":\"100101\",\"CLI_NO\":\"\",\"SERVICE_LEVEL\":\"\",\"EMPLOYEE_NUMBER\":\"\",\"PAY_METHOD\":\"                \",\"CU_NAME\":\"\",\"PU_ORDER_FL\":\"Y\",\"DELIVERY_FL\":\"\",\"ENTRY_FL\":\"\"},{\"CO_ODNO\":\"100165          \",\"CO_STATUS\":\"D\",\"ROUTE_CODE\":\"3   \",\"ROUTE_STOP\":0,\"PRIOR_NAME\":\"\",\"CU_NO\":\"21046     \",\"SHIP_TO\":\"21046     \",\"ORDER_DT_TM\":\"\\/Date(1045771536000)\\/\",\"ORDER_REQD_DT\":\"\\/Date(1043125260000)\\/\",\"SHIP_REQD_DT\":\"\\/Date(1043125260000)\\/\",\"ORDER_TYPE\":\"LIC\",\"CARRIER\":\"\",\"TIMESTAMP\":\"\\/Date(1138107143000)\\/\",\"ORDER_DEL_DT\":\"\\/Date(1138107143000)\\/\",\"TRAFFIC_REF_NO\":\"\",\"SITE\":3,\"PALLET_CUBE\":-1,\"HOST_ODNO\":\"100165\",\"CLI_NO\":\"\",\"SERVICE_LEVEL\":\"\",\"EMPLOYEE_NUMBER\":\"\",\"PAY_METHOD\":\"                \",\"CU_NAME\":\"\",\"PU_ORDER_FL\":\"N\",\"DELIVERY_FL\":\"\",\"ENTRY_FL\":\"\"},{\"CO_ODNO\":\"100192          \",\"CO_STATUS\":\"D\",\"ROUTE_CODE\":\"\",\"ROUTE_STOP\":0,\"PRIOR_NAME\":\"\",\"CU_NO\":\"91163     \",\"SHIP_TO\":\"91163     \",\"ORDER_DT_TM\":\"\\/Date(1045775053000)\\/\",\"ORDER_REQD_DT\":\"\\/Date(1045803660000)\\/\",\"SHIP_REQD_DT\":\"\\/Date(1045803660000)\\/\",\"ORDER_TYPE\":\"LIC\",\"CARRIER\":\"\",\"TIMESTAMP\":\"\\/Date(1144859314000)\\/\",\"ORDER_DEL_DT\":\"\\/Date(1045777813000)\\/\",\"TRAFFIC_REF_NO\":\"\",\"SITE\":3,\"PALLET_CUBE\":-1,\"HOST_ODNO\":\"100192\",\"CLI_NO\":\"\",\"SERVICE_LEVEL\":\"\",\"EMPLOYEE_NUMBER\":\"\",\"PAY_METHOD\":\"                \",\"CU_NAME\":\"\",\"PU_ORDER_FL\":\"Y\",\"DELIVERY_FL\":\"\",\"ENTRY_FL\":\"\"}]"}
```

I can't post the screenshot being a new user, but the columns are created correctly and are showing up blank.

Any help solving this issue would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Terry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If seems to my that you make the same errors like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160045/jqgrid-cannot-call-asp-net-webmethod-but-can-with-ajax).

First of all I suppose that in the web method `GetOrders` you use `JavaScriptSerializer` to make serialization of the object which represent the row of the grid and your service return `string`. As the result the JSON representation of the data (the string) will be added to the object with `d` property `{d:result}` and all will be **one more time** converted to JSON. Instead of that your web method should just return the `List<Order>` type. You can verify this is you will use `thegrid.addJSONData(jQuery.parseJSON(data.d))` instead of `thegrid.addJSONData(data)`

I recommend you also don't use complex constructs of `$.ajaxSetup`, `$.ajax` and `$("#orders").jqGrid` with the `datatype` as the function. It was good for jqGrid before `ajaxGridOptions` and `serializeGridData` options was introduced. in jqGrid 3.6 and higher jqGrid can load data from almost any data source directly. See links from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160045/jqgrid-cannot-call-asp-net-webmethod-but-can-with-ajax) ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675625/setting-the-content-type-of-requests-performed-by-jquery-jqgrid/2678731#2678731), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161302/jqgrid-page-1-of-x-pager/3161542#3161542)) for more details and code examples. You can also search for ajaxGridOptions`and`serializeGridData`.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, your input was very valuable.