# jqGrid with Web Service is not working in jsonreader format

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jqgrid-formatter

What i want to do is, i have a web service which returns number of products (from sample Northwind database) in json format and i want to bind returned row to my jqGrid. I tried [JQGrid - Cannot call ASP.NET WebMethod but can with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160045/jqgrid-cannot-call-asp-net-webmethod-but-can-with-ajax?lq=1)
but it didn't work for me with web service.

Then just for a trial I wrote [Web Method] in same aspx page on which i am creating jqGrid then it did work for mtype:"POST". Below is my code.

#### Working Code Without Web Service

Code in ASPX:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            jQuery("#jqGridXML").jqGrid({
                url: "jqGridXML.aspx/GetProducts",
                mtype: "POST",
                ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" },
                datatype: "json",
                serializeGridData: function (postData) {
                    return JSON.stringify(postData);
                },
                jsonReader: {
                root: function (obj) { return obj.d;},
                page:function (obj) {return 1;},
                total: function (obj) {return 1;},
                records:function (obj) { return obj.d.length;},
                id:"0",
                cell:"",
                repeatitems:false
            },
            datatype:"json",
            height:250,
            colName:['ProductId','ProductName','UnitsInStock'],
            colModel:[{name:'ProductId',index:'ProductId',width:100},
            {name:'ProductName',width:100},
            {name:'UnitsInStock',width:100}],
            caption:"Products"
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <table id="jqGridXML"></table>
    <div id="pagerXML"></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Code in .cs file**

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static List<Products> GetProducts()
{
    Products product = new Products();
    return product.GetProducts();
}
```

This is working but if i do not want to write web method in the form. I have added web reference to my application and want to use data from web service. I tried below in jqGrid but did not help me.

```
$(function () {
    jQuery("#jqGridXML").jqGrid({
        url: "http://localhost:49493/jqGrid_HttpHandlers/WebService.asmx/GetProducts",
        mtype: "POST",
```

Rest part is same.

**Code in Web Service**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for WebService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    public WebService()
    {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static List<Products> GetProducts()
    {
        Products product =  new Products();
        return product.GetProducts();
    }


}
```

Could you please help me to understand things. I just started working on jqGrid.

Your help is really appreciated.

**EDIT**

Yes you are correct Dave. I only uncommented below statement and removed static and ran the project without any modification and it did work perfectly.

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]  
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
```

Thanks, but my next doubt, how can i use jqGrids navigator functionality, like Paging, Sorting those things with the same code. 
I have used this,

```
jsonReader: { 
                root: function (obj) { return obj.d;}, 
                page:function (obj) {return 1;}, 
                total: function (obj) {return 1;}, 
                records:function (obj) { return obj.d.length;}, 
                id:"0",
```

but I really do not have idea where exactly this need to be used in my code. Could you please redirect me to correct solution.

Comment: What is the output at http://localhost:49493/jqGrid_HttpHandlers/WebService.asmx/GetProducts ?

Comment: Try to search for your solution in given below link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161302/jqgrid-page-1-of-x-pager/3161542#3161542

Comment: Parag, refer the following link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161302/jqgrid-page-1-of-x-pager/3161542#3161542
It has given solution for paging.

Comment: Refer the folliowing link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161302/jqgrid-page-1-of-x-pager/3161542#3161542

Answer (score 0):

You need to uncomment the `[ScriptService]` attribute (and most of the other decorations are unnecessary). Also, the method cannot be static. [That's only necessary when you declare the methods in ASPX code behind](http://encosia.com/why-do-aspnet-ajax-page-methods-have-to-be-static/).

So, something like this:

```
[WebService]
[ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
  [WebMethod]
  public List<Products> GetProducts()
  {
    Products product =  new Products();
    return product.GetProducts();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are correct Dave. I only uncommented [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] statement and ran the project without any modification and it did work perfectly. how can i use jqGrids navigator functionality, like Paging, Sorting those things with the same code. I have used this, jsonReader: { root: function (obj) { return obj.d;}, page:function (obj) {return 1;}, total: function (obj) {return 1;},records:function (obj) { return obj.d.length;}, id:"0". But i really do not have idea where exactly this need to be used in my code. Could you please redirect me to correct solution.

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't use jqGrid myself. That would probably make more sense as a separate question now that you have the service working (I'd guess that's probably been asked here before, if you search).

Comment: @Parag, I added your edit to your question, which you're able to edit. You can always leave a comment to an answerer, as I am here, to say that you've updated your question.