# In JQGrid add onclick event on img

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I'm very new to JQuery, and I'm having some trouble

```
function Clients(guid)
{
 var that = this;

this.guid = guid;
this.container = $("#Clients_" + that.guid);

this.LoadClients = function () {
 var ids = that.container.find("#clients-tbl").getDataIDs();

    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        var row = that.container.find("#clients-tbl").getRowData(ids[i]);

        var imgView = "<img src='../../Content/Images/vcard.png' style='cursor:pointer;' alt='Open case' onclick=OnClickImage(" + ids[i] + "); />";

        that.container.find("#clients-tbl").setRowData(ids[i], { CasesButtons:  imgView });
    }
}


this.CreateClientsGrid = function () {
    var clientsGrid = that.container.find("#widget-clients-tbl").jqGrid({
.....
 ondblClickRow:function(rowid)
{
   ---
}
  loadComplete: function () {
            that.LoadClients();


        }
 }
 this.OnClickImage=function(idClient){
  ....
 }

 this.Init = function () {
    that.CreateClientsGrid();
};

this.Init();
}
```

The problem is with onclick, because OnClickImage is not global function.
How can I use OnClickImage function?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the `click` event in different ways. For example you can follow the way from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588420/get-row-data-from-jqgrid-button/5591443#5591443). By the way, it works much more quickly as `getRowData` and `setRowData`. Moreover you should save the result of `that.container.find("#clients-tbl")` operation in a variable *outside* of the loop and use use the variable inside the loop. JavaScript is dynamic language and every operation even `ids.length` will be done every time.

One more way would to use `onCellSelect` event **without** `click` event binding. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303471/browser-memory-usage-comparison-inline-onclick-vs-using-jquery-bind/5305904#5305904) which describe the approach and gives the corresponding demo.

Comment: With event onCellSelected, I have problem with ondblClickRow.

Comment: @cashmere: What problem you have with `ondblClickRow`? You can use `beforeSelectRow` instead of `onCellSelected`. You should don't forget to return `true` from the `beforeSelectRow`. You should explain the problem more clear if you want to solve the problem. Posting of the code is the best.