# jQuery loading data into jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid

I'm a first time user of jqGrid, so far I went trough official examples, I'm interested in loading data into grid either using json.

I'm currently looking at, Loading data(JSON Data):
http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Here is a bit of javascript that creates grid :

```
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid(
    {
        url : '<c:url value="${webappRoot}/getdetails" />',
        datatype : "json",
        colNames : [ 'id', 'Location', 'Country Code', 'Type', 'Interval',
                     'Version', 'Last Active', 'Last Login', 'NOTE' ],
        colModel : [
            { name : 'id', width : 10 },
            { name : 'location', width : 75 },
            { name : 'countryCode', width : 50 },
            { name : 'type', width : 40 },
            { name : 'interval', width : 30 },
            { name : 'version', width : 45 },
            { name : 'lastactive', width : 50, align : "right" },
            { name : 'lastlogin', width : 50, sortable : false },
            { name : 'note', width : 50, sortable : false}
        ],
        rowNum : 10,
        rowList : [ 10, 20, 30 ],
        pager : '#pager2',
        width: gridWidth,
        sortname : 'id',
        viewrecords : true,
        sortorder : "desc",
        caption : "JSON Example"
});
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager2',
                        { edit : false, add : false, del : false});
```

`${webappRoot}/getdetails` transforms path to my project like `http://localhost/myProject/getdetails`, I'm using spring MVC(it might be irrelevant).

When I look in firebug this generates this http request :

```
GET http://localhost/newProject/getdetails?_search=false&nd=1304638787511&rows=10&page=1&sidx=id&sord=desc  
200 OK
135ms
```

Here is the response :

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "location": "office_2782",
    "countryCode": "UK",
    "quarter": "500",
    "version": "v3.05",
    "lastactive": "yesterday",
    "lastlogin": "today",
    "note": "no note",
    "type": "read-only"
}
```

When I navigate to JSON tab it all seems same as this, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I'm trying to load only one record for start, and I can't get it working, any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 4):

First of all you are not the first person who has problems understanding how the JSON data should be constructed, what the parameters sent from jqGrid to the server mean and so on. [The official jqGrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data) doesn't contain enough introduction, so the first steps of the jqGrid usage can be a little more difficult than one expect.

The problem which exists in your JSON response from the server is that **it contains only one item of data instead of an array (or list) of items representing the grid rows**. The data should be at least

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "location": "office_2782",
        "countryCode": "UK",
        "quarter": "500",
        "version": "v3.05",
        "lastactive": "yesterday",
        "lastlogin": "today",
        "note": "no note",
        "type": "read-only"
    }
]
```

or better as

```
{
    "total": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "records": 1,
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "location": "office_2782",
            "countryCode": "UK",
            "quarter": 500,
            "version": "v3.05",
            "lastactive": "yesterday",
            "lastlogin": "today",
            "note": "no note",
            "type": "read-only" 
        } 
    ]
}
```

or even as

```
{
    "total": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "records": 1,
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "row": [ "1", "office_2782", "UK", "500", "v3.05",
                     "yesterday", "today", "no note", "read-only" ] 
        } 
    ]
}
```

or

```
{
    "total": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "records": 1,
    "rows": [
        [ "1", "office_2782", "UK", "500",  "v3.05", "yesterday", "today",
          "no note", "read-only" ] 
    ]
}
```

The reason of such strange at the first glance JSON data is that jqGrid is designed to support paging, sorting and filtering/searching of data implemented **on the server**. So the parameters `rows=10&page=1&sidx=id&sord=desc` from the url sent to the server mean that jqGrid asks the server to get the first page (page=1) of the data with the page having 10 rows per page (rows=10). The data should be previously sorted by `id` (sidx=id) in the descending order (sord=desc). If you has small number of rows (under some hundert for example) you can use client based sorting, paging and filtering if you add `loadonce:true` parameter of the jqGrid, but the server based implementation allows you to work with really large dataset having many hundred thousands rows of data with very good performace.

I recommend you to read my [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764709/jqgrid-not-loading-data/5766189#5766189) where I tried to explain how the additional elements of the server response "total", "page" and "records" will be used. The values of the parameters can be encoded in JSON either as numbers or as strings (on your taste).

If the user clicks on the column header of the 'location' column for example jqGrid will send **new request** to the server having `sidx=location&sord=asc` in the url. So it is important to understand, that the server can be asked to provide the data for the grid not once per grid, but many times and the request will contain some parameters chosen by the user who works with the jqGrid.

Defining of `jsonReader` (and sometimes additional `jsonmap` parameters for every column) you describe the structure of the server response. Using the information jqGrid read the response and fill the grid.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/London.htm) shows that with the corresponding `jsonReader` you can read even your original JSON data.

The last advice for you from me would be to consider at the beginning to use [loadError](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) event handle which helps to inform the user about the errors reported by the server. In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500805/asp-net-mvc-2-0-implementation-of-searching-in-jqgrid/5501644#5501644) I have shown how it can be implemented in the case of ASP.NET MVC. I don't use spring MVC myself so I can't give you direct examples of how to better implement the error reporting in spring MVC, but the main idea is the same in any server technology: in case of errors the server should respond with the response having an [error HTTP status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4). Inside of your implementation of the [loadError](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) event handle you decode the response and display the information about the error.

Comment: If you ever find yourself in Melbourne, send me a message, and I'll buy you a cold beer.  That was a _very_ helpful summary.

Comment: @DuncanBayne: Good suggestion! I think that beer is very good for drinking in subtropical Melbourne. I am glad that I could help you, but I don't sure, that I ever visit Australian. Nevertheless thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: @user2393267: You are welcome! The answer is very old. Now there are a lot of new possibilities to load the data. I implemented many new features in the [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) additionally. It's the fork of jqGrid which I develop since more as one year. In general it's very important to know the total number of rows in the grid. In the most cases the usage of `loadonce: true` scenario is the best choice which provides the best performance.

Comment: @user2393267: I'd recommend to try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-4000-20-free-jqgrid.htm) and [another one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-40000-20-free-jqgrid.htm), to use sorting, paging and filtering of data. You will see the speed of large grid, which hold some thousand of rows *locally*, which client-side paging instead of server side paging.

Comment: Great. I'll have a look at it. Moreover, Which's the better alternative, out of datatable and jqgrid ? I am having the option of using any of them.

Comment: @user2393267: I develop free jqGrid, so I know it and I can implement any new feature, which I would miss in it. I fix any reported bugs typically in the same day if I have the demo which reproduce the problem. Thus I can't recommend another one, you should ask another person about that. I posted [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7000725/315935) about my opinion in the choice of grid control. I suppose that you can choose any from there (datatable or jqGrid). It's the matter of taste mostly or we should really go deep in details using some specific use case and some specific scenario