# JQGRID vs DATATABLES

Tags: jqgrid, datatable

i am trying to make a grid . I want to use either JQGRID or DATATABLES 
What i want to know is which one is better for the implementation of grid.
i have all the information about JQGRID from this link

http://www.jqgrid.com/Home.php

and about DATATABLES from this link

http://datatables.net/

i am a bit confused in deciding which one is bettor to use.if someone could tell me what i can do or not do in jqgrid and datatables that would be really helpful.
thanks in advance

Comment: such questions are very difficult to answer. Look at [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7000725/315935) where I describe the complexity.