# Empty Jqgrid when fetching json data from a restful web service using restx server

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have included following libraries files:

```
<script src="JQuery/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jQuery/src/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> </script>
<script src="JQuery/jqgrid_demo38/js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="JQuery/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Using following code to create the grid:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
        url: 'http://localhost:8001/resource/abc/entries',
        mtype: 'GET',
        datatype: "json",
        colNames: ['Trans ID', 'ACC ID', 'Day ID', 'Date', 'Balance'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'Trans_ID', index: 'Trans_ID', width: 130 },
            { name: 'ACC_ID', index: 'ACC_ID', width: 100 },
            { name: 'Day_ID', index: 'Day_ID', width: 100 },
            { name: 'Summary_Date', index: 'Summary_Date', width: 90 },
            { name: 'Balance', index: 'Balance', width: 85 }
        ],
        width: 700,
        heigth: 200,
        imgpath: "jqgrid_demo38/themes/redmond/images",
        loadonce: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        rownumWidth: 40,
        gridview: true,
        multiselect: false,
        paging: true,
        pager: jQuery('#pager2'),
        rowNum: 20,
        rowList: [10, 30, 50],
        scrollOffset: 0,
        sortname: 'Summary_Date',
        sortorder: "desc",
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: "Demo"
    });
});
```

using the following code to define the grid in HTML

```
<table id="list2" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
<div id="pager2" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>
```

Page returns an empty grid with just column heading and without any data from rest service

when clicked on web service link, it returns following data

```
[
    {
        "Trans_ID": 1,
        "ACC_ID": 1,
        "Day_ID": 1,
        "Summary_Date": "2011-05-08",
        "Balance": 100.0
    },
    {
        "Trans_ID": 2,
        "ACC_ID": 2,
        "Day_ID": 1,
        "Summary_Date": "2011-04-08",
        "Balance": 50.0
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You generate wrong data format for the grid. If you can't make any changes on the server side you should add `jsonReader` described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835957/jquery-with-asp-net-mvc-calling-ajax-enabled-web-service/2836817#2836817).

In general the usage of the RESTful services not means that you should post full pure data. jqGrid is designed to support working with **large** dataset. So in the request send to the server there are additional parameters about the page needed to returned. Look at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764709/jqgrid-not-loading-data/5766189#5766189) which describes the problem more clear.

You use `url: 'http://localhost:8001/resource/abc/entries'` which is very bad. You should always use url in the form `url: '/resource/abc/entries'` or any other form **without** the hostname and the port number. Because of security reasons the ajax requests will be **blocked** if you will try to address another site or another port. I recommend you to use `loadError` handler to see which error your have. In the "UPDATED" part of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500805/asp-net-mvc-2-0-implementation-of-searching-in-jqgrid/5501644#5501644) you will find the corresponding code including the demo project which you can download.

**UPDATED:** [Here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user755360.htm) you can find an example how you can modify the code of jqGrid only to display the data produced by the server:

```
$("#list2").jqGrid({
    datatype: 'json',
    url: 'user755360.json',
    colNames: ['Trans ID', 'ACC ID', 'Day ID', 'Date', 'Balance'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'Trans_ID', index: 'Trans_ID', key:true, width: 130, sorttype:'int' },
        { name: 'ACC_ID', index: 'ACC_ID', width: 100, sorttype:'int' },
        { name: 'Day_ID', index: 'Day_ID', width: 100, sorttype:'int' },
        { name: 'Summary_Date', index: 'Summary_Date', width: 90, formatter:'date',
          sorttype:'date' },
        { name: 'Balance', index: 'Balance', width: 85, formatter:'number',
          sorttype:'number' }
    ],
    rowNum: 20,
    rowList: [10, 30, 50],
    gridview: true,
    pager: '#pager2',
    rownumbers: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    jsonReader : {repeatitems: false,
        root: function(obj) {
            return obj;
        },
        page: function (obj) { return 1; },
        total: function (obj) { return 1; },
        records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
    },
    loadonce: true,
    sortname: 'Summary_Date',
    sortorder: "desc",
    height: "100%",
    caption: "Demo"
});
```