# JQGrid Pagination Issue

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid

I am working jqgrid pagination .And stucked at a very basic problem but it is really irritating me.
There are two main aspects of what i am doing.
1. Server side pagination for server side data. 
2. Client side pagination for server side searching

1. In 1st case i am fetching 50 records for every pager button(next,previous,last,first) and also if user enter page number then also correct service call is fetching perfect 50 records for me and setting data. Also as per my requirements i want jqgrid to show total records on the server at the bottom-right side of grid even if grid contains only 50 at current and accordingly total pages should get updated. this is also working properly.
   [image: 1841 is number of records on server but in jqgrid there exists only 50 records .On click of next i am calling service to get next set of 50 records]
2. Actual conflict is here .If i search with some criteria service will return me whole data for search say 300 records. Now all the 300 records are fetched in single service call. So i want client side pagination for this .I am able set 300 records and page number also but view {} to {} and page number  in textbox at the center does not get updated. 
   Is there any way to reset the value of page textbox and view{} to {} to default value ? 
   Please help
   [image]
   [image: This is a image when data is fetched through search so 50 records are returned.So records are updated to 50 and pages are 1. But textbox value is set to 37 and view 1801-1850 0nly.Ideally it should be page 1 and view 1 to 50 Please help on this]

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that you post wrong values in `total`, `page` and `records` of the server response. I suppose that you switched the values of `records` and `total`. The value of `total` should be the total number of *pages* in the dataset. The value of `records` should be the number of rows (records, items) in the dataset. You should either adjust your server code of specify `jsonReader` which get (calculate) in correct way the data `total`, `page` and `records` from the data returned from the server.

I recommend you to read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5766189/315935) to understand why jqGrid send to the server additional parameters and why the server require to return `total`, `page` and `records`.