# How to load data in pagewise - jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am working on `jqgrid`

I want to customize **jqgrid pagination.**

#### Requirement:

Suppose I have 100000 records which I need to load in the jqGrid but not all at once because it takes a lot of time. So, I want to load first 100 records at first load of page. And then I will load next 100 using ajax call while clicking next page and so on.

Any suggestion will be grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement can be easy implemented in jqGrid. By the way the requested functionality in the oldest way implemented in jqGrid.

jqGrid have `url` option. jqGrid makes request to the URL which includes some additional parameters which default names are `page`, `rows`, `sidx`, `sord`. One can use `prmNames` [option](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) to rename the parameter. It you for example create new grid with options: `url: "MyUrl"`, `datatype: "json"`, `rowNum: 100`, `sortname: "soomeMyColumnName"` then jqGrid will send HTTP GET request (if you don't use `mtype: "POST"` additionally) which looks like `MyUrl?page=1&rows=100&sidx=soomeMyColumnName&sord=asc`. The server should return first 100 items (or less) of data sorted by `soomeMyColumnName` in JSON format described [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data). The response should inform jqGrid about the total number of pages and records additionally to the data itself. You should use either `pager` or `toppager: true` or both parameters to create pager/pagers in the grid which Fisrt/Previous/Next/Last buttons and the possibility to request page by direct page number. See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:pager) and [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5766189/315935) for more details.