# JqGrid in asp.net is not binding

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am trying to implement jqGrid in asp.net.

Here is my code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/plugins/grid.postext.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


     <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#tdList").jqGrid({
    type: "POST",
        datatype: function() {
            $.ajax
            ({

                url: "WebService1.asmx/GetDataFromDB",
                 data: "{}",
                datatype: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",


            });
        },

        height: "100%",
        width: "100%",
        forceFit: true,
        colNames: ['EmpID', 'Name', 'MGR'],
        colModel: [
                    { name: 'EmpID', index: 'EmpID', key: true, hidden: true },
                    { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 100 },
                    { name: 'MGR', index: 'MGR', width: 100 }
                  ],
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [5, 10, 15],
        pager: $('#pager'),
        sortname: 'EmpID',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption: "Customer List"



    }).navGrid('#pager', { del: false, add: false, edit: false });
    });
```

and the code behind is

```
namespace JqGrid_App{    
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ToolboxItem(false)]

[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = false)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]
    public string GetDataFromDB()
    {
        _Default OGetData = new _Default();
       return  OGetData.GetDataFromDB();
    }
}}
```

The JSONData returning has the format

```
{
"total":1,
"page":1,
"records":1,
"rows":[
    {"id":"6","cell":["Robbie","2"]}
       ]
}
```

But the grid is not binding data.

Please help. What I am doing wrong here. I am trying to fix this for last 2 days.

Best Regards,
Mlg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make too many errors in your code:

- You included both `query.jqGrid.min.js` and `query.jqGrid.src.js` instead of the usage only *one* from the files.
- Your `GetDataFromDB` methor return results as `string` which is wrong. You should return the object having properties `total`, `page`, `rows` and so on. Currently you make manual JSON serialization and the resulting string will be serialized *one more time*.
- You use `datatype` as function, which was needed many years ago before was introduced new parameters described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675625/setting-the-content-type-of-requests-performed-by-jquery-jqgrid/2678731#2678731) for example. Your current implementation `datatype` function is wrong because it makes *asynchronous* Ajax call and return before it receive any results from the server. The server results will be discarded.
- Your JSON data returned from the server contains *two* strings for the row of the grid (`["Robbie","2"]`), but you defines *tree* columns
- ...

I can continue...

So I suggest you just look at some other code example which uses ASMX web services with jqGrid. [Here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/TestWebApplicationWithjqGrid.zip) for example you can download one working demo. In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835957/jquery-with-asp-net-mvc-calling-ajax-enabled-web-service/2836817#2836817) you will find another demo.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Oleg for pointing out the errors and providing the links. I corrected the errors and now it is working.

Cheers, Mlg